# jQuery Change event on an <input> element - any way to retain previous value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, forms

I've been searching around this morning and I'm not finding any simple solutions... basically, I want to capture a change in an input element, but also know the previous value.

Here's a change event and an input element in its simplest form. Clearly, I can get the new value with $(elem).val(), but is there a sneaky method I'm missing for getting the previous value? I don't see anything in the jQuery API to do this, but maybe someone's already done this and has some tips?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myInputElement').bind('change', function(){
            //var oldvalue = ???
            var newvalue = $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="myInputElement" type="text">
```

I'm not against writing my own solution, I just want to make sure I'm not recreating the wheel here.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A better approach is to store the old value using .data. This spares the creation of a global var which you should stay away from and keeps the information encapsulated within the element. A real world example as to why Global Vars are bad is documented [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20091030191126/http://billyreisinger.com/blog/2009/01/real-world-example-of-why-global-variables-are-bad/)

e.g

```
<script>
    //look no global needed:)

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Get the initial value
       var $el = $('#myInputElement');
       $el.data('oldVal',  $el.val() );


       $el.change(function(){
            //store new value
            var $this = $(this);
            var newValue = $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
       })
       .focus(function(){
            // Get the value when input gains focus
            var oldValue = $(this).data('oldVal');
       });
    });
</script>
<input id="myInputElement" type="text">
```

Comment: I learn something new every day about jQuery... this is the first I've seen of .data() so I'll definitely read more about it today.

Comment: Wow... ok, thank you, thank you, thank you for turning me on to .data()!!! I just got done reading up on this, and this will change my application to be MUCH more manageable. Gone are my custom, very invalid, attributes storing data.

Ok, now what's the proper StackOverflow etiquette here - I've already marked an answer, but there's an even better one now... do I mark this one?

Comment: There are no hard and set rules regarding this that I have seen. Which answer would you want to see if you googled and found this Q&A this tomorrow?

Comment: IMO, only inexperienced programmers are going to have problems with global variables.

Comment: Not true, even MS render global vars in there ms ajax scripts that can catch people out when they happen to name their control the same as the global var. Def not an inexperienced only problem

Comment: @redsquare: This is great but looks like some logic isn't quite right. `.data('oldVal')` is only ever set when the page is loaded and never after. Probably in the `change` or `focus` event it should be something like `$(this).data('oldVal',  $(this).val())`?

Comment: @Alex-Angas, I took it that he wanted the previous value as in the value when the form was rendered to the screen, not after every change whilst on the screen as that makes no sense really

Comment: Be aware that a checkbox doesn't not always fire a `focus` event.

Answer (score 16):

This might do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=text]").change(function() {
        $(this).data("old", $(this).data("new") || "");
        $(this).data("new", $(this).val());
        console.log($(this).data("old"));
        console.log($(this).data("new"));
    });
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/t26g4/)

Comment: I like this solution but it lacks one thing: if the value is changed by other javascript code (as in my case) or if you need the old value for the first time this code won't work. You'll need to add `<input data-new="initialValue" />` in your HTML and you must overwrite this value on each manipulation.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#element').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).prop("defaultValue"));
});
```

Comment: The simplest way to do this - should have more votes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/how-safe-reliable-cross-browser-compatible-is-this0-defaultvalue

Comment: True, this should be the accepted answer: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp

Comment: This is incorrect according to my understanding of _previous value_. `defaultValue` is the one that was set on page load. Previous value (according to my understanding) is the control's value before a change. If default value is 1 and user types 2, then changes it to 3, the _previous value_ would be 2.

Answer (score 4):

You could have the value of the input field copied to a hidden field whenever focus leaves the input field (which should do what you want).  See code below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myInputElement').bind('change', function(){
            var newvalue = $(this).val();
        });
        $('#myInputElement').blur(function(){
            $('#myHiddenInput').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="myInputElement" type="text">
```

(untested, but it should work).

Comment: This isn't a bad idea... I'll have to test. I wonder if the bind and blur events fire in the same order every time... if so, that may work. Alternatively, I may be able to use the focus event so that when an element is focused, I store the value. Then on change, I have the old and new values...  I'll do some testing and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I did some testing and the focus method works brilliantly. Thanks to both of you for the ideas/samples!

Answer (score 2):

Every DOM element has an attribute called defaultValue. You can use that to get the default value if you just want to compare the first changing of data.

Answer (score 1):

In Russ answer he binds the focus event. I don't think it is necessary.

You can store the old value in the change event.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var newValue = $('#myInputElement').val();
        var oldValue;

        $('#myInputElement').change(function(){
            oldValue = newValue;
            newValue = $(this).val();
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="myInputElement" type="text">
```

Comment: Daniel, the problem with this is that you only get the old value once. Because my form submits through a webservice (ajax), the document only loads once, but the form values can change N number of times. By using the focus method, I'm guaranteed to pick up the new input value.

Comment: Oh, actually - I see what you're doing... my mistake.  Yeah, this would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Some points.

**Use $.data Instead of $.fn.data**

```
// regular
$(elem).data(key,value);
// 10x faster
$.data(elem,key,value);
```

Then, You can get the previous value through the event object, without complicating your life:

```
    $('#myInputElement').change(function(event){
        var defaultValue = event.target.defaultValue;
        var newValue = event.target.value;
    });
```

Be warned that defaultValue is NOT the last set value. It's the value the field was initialized with. But you can use $.data to keep track of the "oldValue"

I recomend you always declare the "event" object in your event handler functions and inspect them with firebug (console.log(event)) or something. You will find a lot of useful things there that will save you from creating/accessing jquery objects (which are great, but if you can be faster...)

Answer (score 1):

I created these functions based on Joey Guerra's suggestion, thank you for that. I'm elaborating a little bit, perhaps someone can use it. The first function checkDefaults() is called when an input changes, the second is called when the form is submitted using jQuery.post. div.updatesubmit is my submit button, and class 'needsupdate' is an indicator that an update is made but not yet submitted.

```
function checkDefaults() {
    var changed = false;
        jQuery('input').each(function(){
            if(this.defaultValue != this.value) {
                changed = true;
            }
        });
        if(changed === true) {
            jQuery('div.updatesubmit').addClass("needsupdate");
        } else {
            jQuery('div.updatesubmit').removeClass("needsupdate");
        }
}

function renewDefaults() {
        jQuery('input').each(function(){
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
        });
        jQuery('div.updatesubmit').removeClass("needsupdate");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a dirty trick but it works, you could use the hover function to get the value before change!

Comment: That wouldn't work if the user uses the keyboard to go to the input box.

Comment: What about using `focus`? that should catch both mouse and keyboard