# val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers

I'm trying to trigger the `change` event on a text box when I change its value with a button, but it doesn't work. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/9z7h2upc/).

If you type something in the text boxes and click somewhere else, `change` is triggered. However, if you click the button, the text box value is changed, but `change` doesn't trigger. Why?

Comment: Title itself answered my question. Confirmed at **[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** yellow "Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using .val() for example, won't fire the event."

Comment: Wish I'd have come across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value sooner, hope it helps some.

Answer (score 555, accepted):

`onchange` only fires when the user types into the input and then the input loses focus.

You can manually call the `onchange` event using after setting the value:

```
$("#mytext").val( 777 ).change(); // someObject.onchange(); in standard JS
```

Alternatively, you can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event using:

```
$("#mytext").val( 777 ).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Is there a reason that jQuery guys didn't implement this?

Comment: feel free to extend jquery and add a say valWithChange function that will do what you want. It cannot be the default action as many times you do not want the event triggering from an automated value change, only when a user interacts with the element

Comment: I would like to see this answer edited to address the option of chaining `.change()` to the `.val()` method.

Comment: The reason may be that some people call `.val()` in `.change()` because they do input validation. Triggering `.change()` on `.val()` would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Only if they were changing the value to something that would fail their own validation, which would be silly.

Comment: I ended up binding to `blur` to accomplish something similar: `$('#mytext').focus().val('New text').blur();`

Comment: @WesJohnson Thanks, as the text input types don't fire change until focus loss, it is necessary to trigger focusin and focusout in combination with this answer. It's also very compact the way you wrote it ;-)

Comment: If you trigger 'change' this way it will not care if the value has actually changed or not.

Comment: For JS Vanilla you can use `el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));`

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the two options you have provided?

Comment: $("#mytext").trigger("input") has been the solution for me!

Answer (score 68):

From redsquare's excellent suggestion, this works nicely:

```
$.fn.changeVal = function (v) {
    return this.val(v).trigger("change");
}

$("#my-input").changeVal("Tyrannosaurus Rex");
```

Answer (score 31):

You can very easily override the `val` function to trigger change by replacing it with a proxy to the original `val` function.

just add This code somewhere in your document (after loading jQuery)

```
(function($){
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(){
        var result =originalVal.apply(this,arguments);
        if(arguments.length>0)
            $(this).change(); // OR with custom event $(this).trigger('value-changed');
        return result;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

A working example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GdEfL/)

(Note that this will always trigger `change` when `val(new_val)` is called even if the value didn't actually changed.)

If you want to trigger change ONLY when the value actually changed, use this one:

```
//This will trigger "change" event when "val(new_val)" called 
//with value different than the current one
(function($){
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(){
        var prev;
        if(arguments.length>0){
            prev = originalVal.apply(this,[]);
        }
        var result =originalVal.apply(this,arguments);
        if(arguments.length>0 && prev!=originalVal.apply(this,[]))
            $(this).change();  // OR with custom event $(this).trigger('value-changed')
        return result;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Live example for that: http://jsfiddle.net/5fSmx/1/

Comment: Hmm, unnecessary duck-patching, I think :-p. Might be better to, as [commented by redsquare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery#comment3273526_3179392), give such a function a different name than `.val()`.

Comment: If you rename it you should change your existing code - 
this way your existing code will continue to work

Comment: But then all of the code which was written with the correct definition of `.val()` in mind would suddenly start producing side-effects :-p.

Comment: This will also make plugins malfunction, which might not be as easily fixable

Comment: In order to avoid side effects, I modified the val function as above, but I'm triggering a different event ("val"), which lets me keep the existing code but easily handle it whenever I need to: 
$(...).on('change val', ...)

Comment: This is an excellent solution in the case you have no control over the code calling `.val()` like using external library. And if you trigger a custom event, it does not cause any harm.

Comment: This is good, but can you show how you would limit it to just one particular input?

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant solution! This seems to be the correct answer, considering you're not always in control over the entire code base (e.g. using external libraries). Nice and clean.

Answer (score 26):

You need to chain the method like this:

```
$('#input').val('test').change();
```

Answer (score 14):

No you might need to trigger it manually after setting the value:

```
$('#mytext').change();
```

or:

```
$('#mytext').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the events are not bubbling. Try this:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
  var oldval=$("#mytext").val();
  $("#mytext").val('Changed by button');
  var newval=$("#mytext").val();
  if (newval != oldval) {
    $("#mytext").trigger('change');
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

I tried just a plain old `$("#mytext").trigger('change')` without saving the old value, and the `.change` fires even if the value didn't change. That is why I saved the previous value and called `$("#mytext").trigger('change')` only if it changes.

Comment: Surprised this didn't have more votes, since it is the current effective implementation of an HTML element change.

Answer (score 6):

As of feb 2019 `.addEventListener()` is not currently work with jQuery `.trigger()` or `.change()`, you can test it below using Chrome or Firefox.

```js
txt.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log('not called?');
})
$('#txt').val('test').trigger('input');
$('#txt').trigger('input');
$('#txt').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

you have to use [`.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) instead.

```js
txt.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log('it works!');
})
$('#txt').val('yes')
txt.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but for others looking, the above solutions are maybe not as good as the following, instead of checking `change` events, check the `input` events.

```
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    // Print entered value in a div box
    $("#result").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Depends on the situation. The "change" and "input" methods both work a bit differently and don't trigger at the same times. The "input" will trigger on every key press, while the "change" triggers when a change has been made, and the input loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

In some case, as it happened for me, when you have a **custom input validation**, which listens to input updates/changes, the `.change()` or `.trigger('change')` wouldn't help.

In such cases, for inputs, you can try using the following:

```js
.trigger('input')
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://api.jquery.com/change/:

The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **attr** and **val** method and then triggering the change:

```
$('.parent-form').find('input').each(function() {
    item = $(this);
    item.attr('value', '0622-03-22');
    item.val('01/01/01').trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are good, but none of them worked for me in 2023 using jQuery 3.7.1 in modern browsers. What did work for me is this:

```
$('#something').val('some value').trigger('keyup');
```

I don’t know what happened with the `change` trigger, but setting the trigger to `keyup` works for me fine nowadays.