# Onchange input event isn't fired on jquery

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm working with jquery.

And i have text input in a form, i would like to process the change event.

```
$("#my_input").change(function(){alert('123');});
```

the event is fired normally when i edit the field manually, but when i change the field's value with a script (sometimes with an external script) it doesn't work.

is there any solution ?

and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change event is not designed to detect programmatic changes. You can trigger the event manually when setting the value, though:

```
$('#my_input').trigger('change');
```

shortcut:

```
$('#my_input').change();
```

Comment: is there an event that fires when the input is changed programmatically ?

Comment: @Youcef04: No, JavaScript does not support that kind of monitoring. Some other languages have constructs that allow stuff like this, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: @Youcef04: It would be nice if you could accept this answer if I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Fire them manually, using one of the following two functions:

```
$('#my_input').trigger('change');
$('#my_input').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use live/delegate to bind your change event

```
$("#my_input").live('change',function(){alert('123');});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
$("input[type='text']").change( function() {
  // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
});
```