# Is there an alternative to using a callback inside of jQuery's .val()?

Tags: jquery, api, callback

I would like an alternative to using callback method inside of jQuery's .val() method (Which it clearly doesn't support). For example:

http://jsbin.com/ilahan/edit#source

```
$("#box").val("The New Value", function(){
  alert("It's changed now");
});
```

Comment: `.val` is an instant change and so there is no need for callback? Why do you need it in first place?

Comment: No, you cannot, as the API docs and your test both clearly indicate. Besides, using a callback does not make sense.

Comment: So, this was a prime example of an XY question -- but I'll leave it up for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) ?

```
$("#box").val("The New Value").change(function(){
  alert("It's changed now");
});
```

---

As Vega stated in his comments, changing the val from code won't trigger the change event no matter what: [.val() doesn't trigger .change() in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

Comment: What does this code do? change the value and register a handler?

Comment: if you chained then in the opposite order you'd even have a handler for the change event when you are setting the value

Comment: @RuneFS even still it doesn't make any sense to add a handler for this question.

Comment: @Vega did I ever claim it did?

Comment: @RuneFS Can you tell me what _you'd even have a handler for the change event when you are setting the value_ means?

Comment: @Vega, you're right... The question seems to be a little odd. I just wanted to point out that .change should be used for callback, not the val() itself. Chaining the calls is just a syntactical sugar.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic I was just trying to say that even after registering `.change`, When updating value via script such as `.val` will not trigger the `.change`. Probably you should mention that and add a `.change()` call at the end of `.val()`. guess I am just being picky.

Comment: @vega that if the code was .change(...).val(...) the call to val would fire the change event and there'd be an event handler to handler that event. Does it make sense? well that depends if you need the event handler or you simply need to execute some code this one time

Comment: I just edited my answer... Wasn't aware that val() doesn't trigger the change event. Thanks @Vega :)

Answer (score 3):

`.val` is an instant change and so there is no need for callback? Why do you need such a callback?

Below code should do the same as what you wanted from a callback on `.val`

```
$("#box").val("The New Value");
alert("It's changed now");
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to do a call back when setting the value, as the change happens immediately.
If you are looking to execute code when the field value changes, you can use:

```
$("#box").change(function(){
    alert('value changed');
});
```