# why does the jquery change event not trigger though the value of input changed indeedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/meXm3/2/)

Html Code:

```
<body>
    <input value="123">
    <button>button</button>
</body>
```

Js Code(using JQuery 1.2.0):

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").val("balabala...");
    });

    $("body").on("change","input",function(){
        alert("change");
        alert($("input").val());
    });
});
```

**Question:**
At the beginning, the value of the input is "123".

When I change the text through editing by hands and click other places not the input field, the change event of the input will trigger.

However, when I click the button, which will also change the value of the input, the change event of the input will not work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery

Comment: @Todd, thanks, they are similar and near to the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `change` event is not triggered when changing the value programatically with code, you have to trigger it yourself

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").val("balabala...").trigger('change');
    });

    $("body").on("change","input",function(){
        alert("change");
        alert($("input").val());
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/meXm3/3/)

Comment: Ooh, just out of interest, what's the difference between using `.trigger('change')` and `.change()`?

Comment: No difference for this case really, jQuery just has a special `trigger()` method that does this, and it accepts more options than just using `.change()`

Comment: @BeatAlex Both of methods work, but I do not know the difference in details.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meXm3/4/)

You need to append `.change()` onto the `click` function:

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").val("balabala...").change();

    });

    $("body").on("change","input",function(){
        alert("change");
        alert($("input").val());
    });
});
```