# jQuery: Validation of Values in Input Fields

Tags: jquery, validation

*I'm building a form.*

I have two input fields (`#totalIncome` and `#totalExpenses`). I need to confirm that the value of those two fields equal the equation `#totalIncome > #totalExpenses` before the user will be able to send the form. I'm struggling with the jQuery.

If `#totalIncome` isn't greater than `#totalExpenses` I want to display an error message in the `#validation` div (for this example it should display "Income is lower than expenses"). I also want to disable the submit button, `#submit-suggestion`.

If `#totalIncome` actually is greater than `#totalExpenses` I simply want the `#submit-suggestion`-button to be functional.

*This is my code so far:*

```
$('#validation').change(function() {
    if ($('#totalIncome').val() < $('#totalExpenses').val()) {
        $('#validation').val('Income is lower than expenses.')
        $('#submit-suggestion').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#submit-suggestion').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#totalIncome, #totalExpenses').change(function() {
    if (parseFloat($('#totalIncome').val()) < parseFloat($('#totalExpenses').val())) {
        $('#validation').val('Income is lower than expenses.')
        $('#submit-suggestion').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#submit-suggestion').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Simcha, thanks for the response, however, it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I've done something wrong, but would you mind taking a look at the page, where I'm actually doing the testing? It's at https://www.daccusa.org/suggest/. I've implemented your code. The `#totalIncome` and `#totalExpenses` are located at the bottom and the values are determined by the costs, participants and ticket prices.

Comment: `.val()` doesn't trigger change. After you programmatically change the values of `#totalIncome` and `#totalExpenses`, use `$("#totalIncome ").trigger("change")` or `$("#totalExpenses").trigger("change")` . Read more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the decimal value of the input.

```
if ( parseFloat($('#totalIncome').val()) 
                    < parseFloat($('#totalExpenses').val())) {
```

And to display an error, you may have initially a blank `p` element, and then, to show error, set its `innerHTML` to `"Error!Error!"`. Something like:

```
else {
    $('#submit-suggestion').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#error-box').html("Error!"); 
    // or $('#error-box')[0].innerHTML = "Error";
}
```

Also, instead of listening to the `change` event, you might want to fire the validation function `onclick` of a button.

Comment: The `$('#error-box').html("Error!");` is great! However, if I change the values, it will still say _error_. How can I implement some sort of `toggle` on it - do you know?

Comment: @FrederickAndersen Once you are sure what the user entered is correct, you can write: `$("#error-box).html("");`, which empties the contents.