# How to show/hide div when a value is assigned to an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically show a `div` when a value is assigned to a input element.

So far i am using `keyup` function, but this works only if i typed in a value. How can i show/hide a `div` if the value is assigned to the input without me typing it in?

Here is what i have.

```
<script>
$("#ven_id").keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()) {
    $(".inv_item").slideDown(500);
} else {
    $(".inv_item").slideUp(500);
}

});
</script>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: bind focus events for #ven_id $("#ven_id").bind("focus keyup",function(){});

Comment: hi selva, this kinda works but i have to click in the input before it to slide, i don't have to change the number like in my example but i would like it to side without me clicking in the input element

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the change handler. [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$("#ven_id").change(function(event) {
    if(event.target.value) {
        $(".inv_item").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $(".inv_item").slideUp(500);
    }
});
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggh1umek/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i tried this but no luck. works if i type the number in though.

Comment: +1 however, be aware that `change` will get triggered only after `ven_id` has lost focus which might be a bit late depending on what you want to achieve...I'd suggest using a combination of both

Comment: As @Leo said, it will fire when the field loses focus.  Exactly what behavior do you want to see?  If a user types in the box as well as if it is updated through some other mechanism?

Comment: basically i have a popup that passes a value to the input field in a form, everything works well. click even in the popup does assign the value to the input, just that it does not show the div. if i type a number in it rather that being assigned one from the popup, it works.

Comment: @Anand26...why don't you move that logic to its own function so you can reuse it? Then, call the function on `keyup` and then when the popup passes the value to the inout...that should be pretty straight forward

Comment: @Leo has a good suggestion, or you can add a $("#ven_id").blur(); call after you set the textbox value with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is that an event isn't fired when the input's value is set in code. This answers your question I believe [.val() doesn't trigger .change() in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery).

After the popup sets the input's value you need to manually trigger the event.

```
$("#ven_id").val("somevalue").trigger("keyup");
```

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestion as well, this means i will have to click in the input, i was trying for it to show the div automatically.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't being clear with my answer. This will be in conjunction with your previous solution of the keyup event. The keyup event will take care of showing / hiding the div when the user types in the input. The code I've added will trigger the same event when the value is set automatically. Check this out (http://jsfiddle.net/hednsv2f/) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, May it can help You.

```
if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(".inv_item").slideDown(500);
} else {
    $(".inv_item").slideUp(500);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks your your suggestion. i tested it but was not able to get it working. only works if i type the value in.