# jQuery - autoNumeric plugin, fire .change() automatically from .autoNumeric('set', value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, autonumeric.js

I'm using the [autoNumeric jQuery plugin](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/). I want to have the `.autoNumeric('set', value)` method call the `.change()` event automatically.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#baseCost").change(function() {
        var total = ...; // calculation removed for code brevity
        $("#totalCost").autoNumeric('set', total);
    });

    $("#totalCost").change(function() {
        // this code does not fire when the set above is called
    });

});
```

How would I accomplish this?

**Update:** In the autoNumeric.js file, I found this (within `set`):

```
if ($input) {
    return $this.val(value);
}
```

Given that in my case $input is set to true, I don't understand why this `.val()` is not firing the `.change()` on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not realize that `.val()` does not trigger `.change()` by default. For my question specifally, the following does the trick in autoNumeric.js:

```
if ($input) {
    if ($this.val(value)) {
        return $this.trigger("change");
    }
    return false;
}
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/3911632).