# dynamic input on change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic input field which is being generated like this

```
var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="program_id" data-id="'+val['program_id']+'" value="'+val['program_id']+'">'+programBtn+'</td></tr>';
$('#transaction').append(field);
$('#transaction').on('change', 'input',function() {
    console.log('hi');
});
```

And i have a button that when i click, it will input data into that input field using

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).data('text');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#transaction').find('input:'+id).val(text);
});
```

Ok if i click the button it will fill in those values but console.log('hi') isnt firing. But if i type in the text box and then i leave focus it, i can see console.log('hi') is firing. Note that code here is just an example.

My Jquery version is 3.2.1

Comment: Is `#transaction` also a table? Since tr can only go in a `table` or `tbody`.

Comment: `#transaction`- is it `table` id or  `tbody` id? because `$('#table')` you have mentioned in click event handler.

Comment: Yes sorry i have edited now, #transaction is a table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger `change function` as soon as you change the `input value` since `change fn` will be triggered only when the user changes the value manually and losses the focus.
you can trigger that using `.trigger('change')` or `change()`

```js
var field = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="program_id" data-id="11" value="test"></td></tr>';
$('#transaction').append(field);
$('#transaction').on('change','input',function() {
    console.log('hi');
});
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).data('text');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#transaction').find('input[data-id="'+ id +'"]').val(text).change();
    //$('#transaction').find('input[data-id="'+ id +'"]').val(text).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="transaction">Transaction: </div>
<button data-text="Some Text" data-id="11">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're finding input element that has `data-id` with value equal to `data-id` on the clicked button. If that so, you might use

```
$('#transaction').find('input[data-id="+ id +"]')
```

And from [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/5816907). `onchange` only fires when the user types into the input and then the input loses focus. So, you need to trigger the event manually.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).data('text');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#transaction').find('input[data-id="+ id +"]').val(text).change(); // trigger change event
});
```