# "on change" does not fire when programatically select an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/WaPXWo?editors=1010) that loads `cities` after a `country` is selected..., now with `//$("#country").val("3");` code commented the "manual" change of the coutry works well.

But the "automatic" (code uncommented) load of the `country` does not change the cities... why?

**PS.** I don't want to trigger "change" event manually. for me is strange I should do it by hand...

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

var countries = {
  "1": ["Paris", "Lyon"],
  "2": ["Berlin", "Cologne"],
  "3": ["London", "Edinburgh"]
};

function loadCities(countryId) {
  var cities = countries[countryId];
  var container = "#city";
  $(container).empty();
  $(container).append($("<option/>", { value: 0, text: "select a city..." }));
  $.each(cities, function(key, city) {
    $(container).append($("<option/>", { text: city }));
  });
}

$("#country").on("change", function() {
  var countryId = $(this).val();
  loadCities(countryId);
});

$("#country").val("3");//.trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="0">select a country</option>
  <option value="1">France</option>
  <option value="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="3">UK</option>
</select>
<select id="city">
  <option value="0">no country selected</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you have a weird mix of js and jQuery going on - what happens when you change the first line to: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

Comment: If you run your snippet, there is an error of  `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`. If you change your snippet to a newer version of jQuery such as 2.x.x, your code works. Try changing the version of jQuery in your snippet.

Comment: @PeterB: I don't want to manually trigger "change".

Comment: @Serge You have to.  Logical changes do not create events.  Events are for user interactions.  This is explained in the duplicate

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky: please see the Codepen, it strange why it does not work, jquery not loading...

Comment: @Serge my first comment on this thread will fix that `ReferenceError` issue

Comment: User @Sv443 made a stupid edit that broke the spelling of Edinburgh + which removed the jQuery library. It is too late to do a rollback of that because you have made an edit on top of it already (which would then also be undone)...

Comment: @PeterB updated the snippet

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs fixed by applying the Alexander suggestion

Comment: I didn't break anything. I just removed the jQuery script tag because it's automatically included

Comment: @Sv443 what is your problem with "Edinburgh"?

Comment: Side point.  The `$.each` is unnecessary.  The key of your cities is your countryId.  You can do just `cities[countryId]`

Comment: @Serge I didn't change a single thing. Like I said, I only made a single edit and that was to remove that first line in the HTML section and I changed the jQuery version in the snippet's settings. I didn't even click on anything else.

Comment: Well I just looked at the revisions and you're right I did somehow change that. I don't know how that happened but alright.

Comment: @Taplar for your "cities[countryId]" remark the "==" sign, that mean, if the keys are integers we sould compare them by value, not by type...

Comment: The only reason you are doing that is because you are looping through all the entries in the object and trying to find the one that has the cities for the countryId.  But it's an object.  You do not have to do that.  The countryId is the key of the object.  I made use of this fact in my answer below

Comment: @Taplar i doing this because in my real example I recieve integers from json as ID, but have strings as key, so "2" and 2 is not the same, I should compare "==", not "==="

Comment: then `countryId.toString()` will fix that.  There's no need for the loop

Comment: @Taplar good point...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to "trigger change" you can always call the function on your own.

```
function selectCountry(countryId) {
    $("#country").val(countryId);
    loadCities(countryId)
}
```

then replace this:

> ```
> $("#country").val("3");//.trigger("change");
> ```

with this:

```
selectCountry("3")
```

Comment: This is actually more preferable, as you are not funnling your logic through the dom.  You're going straight to what you want to do.

Comment: @dovidweisz just please show how to include it in the actual code ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to also trigger the `change` event, like this:

```
$("#country").val("3");
$("#country").trigger("change");
```

`onchange` only fires when the user types into the input and then the input loses focus. It cannot be the default action as many times you do not want the event triggering from an automated value change, only when a user interacts with the element.

The reason may be that some people call `.val()` in `.change()` because they do input validation. Triggering `.change()` on `.val()` would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Nu, I would like to use "select" event maybe... instead of "change"

Comment: you can extend jquery and add a say `valWithChange` function that will do what you want.

Comment: Or use a namespace like ```change.country```.

Comment: You could also write the above like: ```$("#country").val("3").change();```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var cities = {
    "1": ["Paris", "Lyon"],
    "2": ["Berlin", "Cologne"],
    "3": ["London", "Edinburgh"]
  };

  function loadCities(countryId) {
    //get the city names if we can
    var cityNames = cities[countryId];
    //get a reference to the container
    var $container = $('#city');
    //create an array of the options we want to replace the city with
    //building a list of the options allows us to optimize in two ways
    //1) Not using jQuery to create the options removes some overhead with
    //   jQuery creating the DOM nodes one at a time
    //2) Replacing all the options at the end reduces the number of times
    //   you manipulate the DOM and reduce the number of times it has to
    //   perform calculations about how it is going to re-draw the page
    var options = ['<option value="0">select a city...</option>'];
    
    //we will have cityNames if the countryId is not 0
    if (cityNames) {
      //make an option for each city
      cityNames.forEach(function(city){
        options.push('<option>'+ city +'</option>');
      });
    } else {
      //user did not select a country, default the city back to the original
      //message
      options = ['<option value="0">no country selected</option>'];
    }
    
    //replace all the options with the new options.  This will be a single
    //DOM change
    $container.html(options);
  }

  $("#country")
    //bind the on change like we were before
    .on("change", function() {
      var countryId = $(this).val();
      loadCities(countryId);
    })
    //also change the value
    .val("3");
  //call loadCities directly to update the city dropdown
  loadCities("3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="0">select a country</option>
  <option value="1">France</option>
  <option value="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="3">UK</option>
</select>
<select id="city">
  <option value="0">no country selected</option>
</select>
```

Comment: good, but I want my "val("3")" updates automatically the values if possible.. there should not be the need to call "loadCities("3");"

Comment: This has already been explained with the fact that logical changes do not create events.

Comment: my logical change updates the selected value and the text of the select element. this is an event for me...

Comment: It's not an event for javascript.  You have to work with the language.