# How can launch a event on a input when the value its coming from a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example ill have a filter function but it will only search value in the table if i type inside the input text field, so i what i need help on is that i want that this function filters data when the input is changed by code not by a user inserting text inside the input.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txtSearch").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tblSearch tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

This second script will change the value of the txtSearch input to explain how i want the filter option to be working. By a changed input but not when a user type on it.

function selectedRow(){
            var index,
         table = document.getElementById('taCiclo');

```
        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function()
            {
                document.getElementById("id_ciclo").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            //i've tried the trigger or eventDispatcher is this part too, but is not working at all.
           document.getElementById("id_ciclo").value ;


                  if(typeof index !== "undefined"){
                   table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
                }
                console.log(typeof index);

                index = this.rowIndex;

                this.classList.toggle("selected");
                console.log(typeof index);
                };
        }
    }   
    selectedRow();
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger

Comment: Try `$("#txtSearch").val(12).trigger('change');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

Comment: it actually worked @AswinKumar, but i just edit with my real problem. thats they way how im getting the value into my input.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i soved it, thanks for yout help!

```
 var el =   document.getElementById("id_ciclo"); 
            el.value=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```