# Using jquery Autocomplete with fields that have a change selector

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a handful of fields:

```
 <input type='text' id='field1' name='field1' class='checkMe'>
 <input type='text' id='field2' name='field2' class='checkMe'>
 <input type='text' id='field3' name='field3' class='checkMe'>
```

I have a jquery autocomplete function:

```
 $('#someField').autocomplete({
       /// options
       $.ajax({
           ////
           success:function(result){
                 $.each(result,function(e,i){
                      $('#'e).val(i);
                      // -- e is a valid id of a text field

                 });
           }
       });
 });
```

the autocomplete part works fine.  I also have another event listener for those fields:

```
  $('.checkMe').bind('keyup change', function () {
      alert('hi');
          //do something
  });
```

Users on this page can either fill out form by entering values in each field, or selecting a field somewhere else and let autocomplete fill out form.

Problem:  When user enters data manually, .checkMe fires correctly,  When user uses autocomplete,  the .checkMe event never fires.

Comment: you need to trigger yourself, `val` does not, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/7393478)

Answer (score 0):

as seen in [val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

The solution was to add:

```
 $('#'e).val(i).trigger("change");
```

in my autocomplete.