# jQuery .val() Not Actually Changing Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

**UPDATE:** I feel like I may have left out a key piece of information... The column type is a Person or Group type. I tried with a single line of text and it works just fine. Doesn't register as empty.But for other entries/pre-filled inputs need to use the Person or Group column to determine other inputs. Working with metadata

I have a SP list where for my first column, I am having the form autofill the User using an AJAX.

It populates the field with the correct value no problem. My issue is when you can see the value that has been automatically placed there, and hit submit for the form, it still reads the field as blank and tells me "You cannot leave this blank".

You see the value there, but it is kind of pushed in the left corner of the text box, hidden beside the input boxes default Placeholder text. I am wondering if that also could maybe be causing an issue? Is it possible to hide the placeholder text?

If I click the text box, and press any key (Enter/space/etc.) then it notices the value automatically inserted.

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, I have done my due diligence searching through posts and threads and have found similar posts with this issue, but the solution does not work. Like this post here:
[val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

Here is my call and appending of the information:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: webUri + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(dataCurrentUser){
            console.log(dataCurrentUser)
            $("[title='User']").val(dataCurrentUser.d.AccountName).keyup().change();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Let's see your markup. Also, `$().val(dataCurrentUser.d.AccountName).keyup().change();` is mildly more performant (and looks cooler).

Comment: I'd bet that `.focus().blur()` would do the job. To be accessible you'd want to then return focus to the calling element.

Comment: Are you sure you are not incurring in asynchronous issue? If the validation occurs before the success callback for example

Comment: @DanielA.White I will have to create one which would take a bit. That is all of my JS within a <script> tag and initialization of jquery plugin. This is all through form created by SharePoint

Comment: @Greedo would a promise fix such issue? As opposed to using a slow ajax?

Comment: @BeerusDev that can be a solution that avoid chaining callback (that can be quite tricky to debug if they are a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test code for your reference:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties",
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function (dataCurrentUser) {
        console.log(dataCurrentUser)
        var ppTitle = "people";
        //$("[title='people']").val(dataCurrentUser.d.DisplayName).keyup().change();
        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + ppTitle + "']");
        var peoplePickerEditor = _PeoplePicker.find("[title='" + ppTitle + "']");
        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
        peoplePickerEditor.val(dataCurrentUser.d.DisplayName);
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
        ppobject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
      }

    })
  })
</script>
```

Blog reference:
[People Picker Field Actions In SharePoint Using JavaScript (JSOM)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/people-picker-field-actions-in-sharepoint-using-javascript-jsom/)

**Updated:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (dataCurrentUser) {
                    console.log(dataCurrentUser)
                    var ppTitle = "people";
                    //$("[title='people']").val(dataCurrentUser.d.DisplayName).keyup().change();
                    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + ppTitle + "']");
                    var peoplePickerEditor = _PeoplePicker.find("[title='" + ppTitle + "']");
                    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
                    peoplePickerEditor.val(dataCurrentUser.d.DisplayName);
                    var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
                    ppobject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
                }

            })
        })
    });

</script>
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amos, but I run into quite a few errors when trying this.

Comment: The first: ```SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined``` so I added the script ```<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>``` as referred to here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268699/how-to-resolve-javascript-spclientpeoplepicker-is-not-defined-in-edge-works-fi. Then I try it again and I receive this error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor' of undefined```

Comment: And it does not populate to the input box like my previous code. Trying to search for a solution

Comment: Works like a charm!