# textarea events not triggered upon .val()

Tags: jquery, textarea, onchange, eventtrigger

When I run

```js
$("textarea").val("hello");
```

the events that Firefox developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) reports are bound to this textarea,

[image],

are not triggered. How do I trigger them?

###### Running `$("textarea").val("hello")`:

[image]

###### Manually inputting text:

[image]

This textarea is on a website that has all sorts of code to prevent automated entry into the textarea. Even running a JavaScript or jQuery `.click()` on the textarea doesn't select it.

Appending `.change()`, as suggested by [an answer to "val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/1429450), doesn't work for me, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that [events not bound with jQuery cannot be triggered with jQuery](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-event-trigger-doesnt-work#14737000000302229), so you will have to trigger the change event using JavaScript:

```
let element = document.getElementById(idOfTextArea);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));
```

<sup>source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50587874/1429450) to "[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2490825/1429450)"</sup>