# <input> text change events

Tags: javascript, events, text, input

Is there a library that can extract all text events from an `<input type=text>` (or contentEditable -- any one-line input field) element?

In particular, I need to know whenever the text is changed by:

- typing (asdf, backspace)
- cut/paste
- key combo actions (e.g. ctrl+bksp or option+bksp deletes the previous word)
- dragged & dropped text
- edit menu actions

And preferably what it was that changed (whether and what text was inserted, deleted, or replaced).

Needs to work on Chrome, Safari, Firefox 3+, IE9+.

Comment: Were you able to achieve what you were looking for? What did you use finally?

Comment: I used the `oninput` event as described in the accepted answer. There's no way to find the changed text, but you can see how sharejs does it: https://github.com/share/ShareJS/blob/master/lib/client/textarea.js

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The HTML5 `oninput` event is supported by all those browsers and works very much like the `onchange` event, but fires as soon as the element's input changes.  It also bubbles, so you can capture it further up the document tree.

```
element.oninput = function () {

}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfthe/**

http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Comment: I knew what I'd find when I saw this question in the list, and sure enough, there was your answer :)

Comment: @Tim: Ha! I feel like I'm beginning to sound like a broken record :-)  At least this question wasn't riddled with answers saying *"use onkeyup!"*...

Comment: @nornagon: can't be done in a straightforward/easy manner. The event doesn't expose anything like that in a property so you'd have to store the previous value in a variable and update that variable every time the text changes, comparing the two values.

Comment: I don't want to write a diff algorithm just to work out what happened :( I'm using this to interface with a Wave-like operational transform library, so the deltas are important. Would it be easier with a contentEditable element?

Comment: @nornagon: nope, afraid not.  If anything, it would be more difficult because you're diffing HTML rather than text.

Comment: @nornagnon, @Andy: Also, the `input` event is not yet generally supported on contenteditable, so the situation is even worse.

Comment: i guess the only way to do it is to catch every key event and guess what it was supposed to do :/ running LCS on every keystroke quickly becomes unviable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday and came up with a solution to diff old and new text input values.

The output is like this:

*Old value: test test

New value: test w

Change: overwrote 'test' with 'w' at position 5*

The script uses window.setInterval() to avoid cross browser problems (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949416/727190). This causes some changes to be batched when the user types really fast - this could be a good thing, depends on your situation.

You can, however, easily modify the script to work off events.

http://jsfiddle.net/6zp48/2/

Excerpt from fiddle showing the result of the diff (the findChange() code is too long to paste here):

```
var changeType = { added: 0, deleted: 1, overwrite: 2 };
var previousValue = '';

window.setInterval(checkChange, 100);

function checkChange() {
    var newValue = $("#input1").val();
    if(newValue != previousValue) {
        showChange(findChange(previousValue, newValue));
        previousValue = newValue;
    }
}

function showChange(result) {
    $("#last-change").html("Prev: " + previousValue + "<br/>Next:" + $("#input1").val() + "<br/>");

    if(result == null)  {
        $("#last-change").html($("#last-change").html() + " no change detected");
        return;
    }

    switch (result.change) {
        case changeType.added:
            $("#last-change").html($("#last-change").html() + "added '" + result.added.text + "' at position " + result.added.position + "<br />");
            break;
        case changeType.deleted:
            $("#last-change").html($("#last-change").html() + "deleted '" + result.lost.text + "' at position " + result.lost.position + "<br />");
            break;
        case changeType.overwrite:
            $("#last-change").html($("#last-change").html() + "overwrote '" + result.lost.text + "' with '" + result.added.text + "' at position " + result.added.position + "<br />");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ShareJS has a [neat way of finding changes](https://github.com/josephg/ShareJS/blob/master/src/client/textarea.coffee#L7) in a `<textarea>`. Basically: it looks for the first character that's changed and the last character that's changed and assumes everything in the middle was just replaced.

Comment: Nice find! Would that work for things like the user selecting and dragging text around in the textarea, or pasting?

Comment: Yep, should work for anything. It won't always find the minimal possible delta or even a very smart delta, but it will always be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer

```
$('input').on('keydown keyup click input submit mouseenter', function (e) {
    // Handle e.type
    alert('Type: ' + e.type);
});
```

Append supported or custom events, it should work. I hope this helps someone
See Jquery Documentation for more help. http://api.jquery.com/on/