# Text changed event on jQuery when not fired with keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to fire an event every time I change the text on an `<input type="text">` when the changes are not made pressing keys on the keyboard?

What I mean is I want to capture when somebody type in, right-click -> paste or drag a selected text on an input and not only when a key is pressed.

I've tried:

```
<input id="some-id" onchange="alert('fired')">
```

and

```
$('#some-id').on('change', ev_handler);
$('#some-id').change(ev_handler);
```

the only event that fires are the ones related to key press but they don't fire on pasting or dragging.

Comment: Looks like if you bind to the 'input' event, it works as expected. See https://gist.github.com/brandonaaskov/1596867

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**oninput** event could met your needs, but just note it's not well supported in older browsers. You can find more info [on Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php).

If you need to cover all browsers and all use cases like you mentioned, there is really no better way then periodically check (for example every 500ms) your input value with JavaScript.

You can find discussion about that [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery).

Answer (score -2):

Try the onChange event, that should be issued everytime the input is changed, no matter how.

Comment: for some reason, neither this <input onchange="alert('fired')"> or any jQuery methods (.on() or .changed()) work on inputs type="text"

Comment: onchange only happens when tabbing out of the text box (or it otherwise loses focus), not immediately when input is entered.

Comment: @rushkeldon true, but that information was added AFTER I've posted my answer. Check the version history of the question...