# How to catch the change of Text property of a Label control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for something similar to the `OnTextChanged` property of a TextBox control. So that when the Text value of a label is changed, a particular function is called to do my particular staff.

**MarkUp**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1"  TargetControlID="TextBox2"  BoundControlID="Label1" Maximum="200" Minimum="100" runat="server">
    </asp:SliderExtender>
```

Comment: And how's your User gonna change text of a label ??

Comment: Maybe it is better to call the function from the slider event.

Comment: @Casperah I'm using the sliderExtender control of AjaxControlToolkit, and there is no OnChange type property there.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the appropriate OnChange event of the slider instead.  The only way the label text can change is if your code changes it.

**EDIT**

Hmmm.  You could try binding the slider to a non-visible asp:TextBox, then use the OnChange event from that to update your Label and call your function.

Comment: I'm using the sliderExtender control of AjaxControlToolkit, and there is no OnChange type property there.

Answer (score 0):

Observing `'input'` event instead of `'change'`

```
jQuery('#textboxid').live('input', function() {
    // do your stuff
})
```

or 
for your slider using `'change'` event

```
$('#sliderid').live('change', function() {
     $('#textboxid').val('some text').trigger('change');
});
```

may be this way instead of change event. (The `'change'` event doesn't work correctly, but the `'input'` is perfect.)

```
$('#your_textbox').bind('input', function() {
    /* This will be fired every time, when textbox's value changes. */
});
```

This jQuery code catches immediate changes to any element,

```
$('.myElements').each(function() {
    // Save current value of element
    $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());

    // Look for changes in the value
    $(this).bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
    // If value has changed...
        if ($(this).data('oldVal') != $(this).val()) {
            // Updated stored value
            $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());

            // Do action
            ....
        }
    });
});
```

by [phatmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885716/)