# Is it possible to avoid submitting empty forms with JSTL?

Tags: java, servlets, jstl

I have a form with a bunch of radio buttons, and a submit button. When a radio button is selected, I'm passing a query string to the servlet for further processing. But when none is selected and the Submit button is pressed, I get an exception, obviously. Is there anyway to avoid this? As in, avoid submitting empty forms using JSTL?

Comment: Don't submit the form unless a selection has been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the submit button until a selection is made.  Try using JavaScript or Jquery

see [JQuery Onselect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869640/jquery-onselect)