# Change Input text as user types into preselected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to recreate the effect in Hackertyper, http://hackertyper.com/ , where as soon as you start typing it triggers the output of preset text.

Could this code help at all?
[Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's basically event binding.

You could also take a look at the original source code to get inspired and see how its done:
http://hackertyper.com/script.js

It's a main event loop bound to the `keydown` event (page start).
Based on that event (the keydown) the pressed key is `key.KeyCode`, which you might use to add text depending on the key. The text is appended by `$("#console").append(str);`
That's it.