# How to trigger a function on value set to a inputbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code where I want to trigger a function on the date value selected to the input box. How can I achieve this using jQuery? Below is my code:

```js
$("input.Degree_date").live('click', function() { 
    $("input.add").attr("hidden", true);
    $("input.delete").attr("hidden", true);
    alert();
});

$(document).on('input', '.Degree_date', function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated for `.on` - since you ALREADY use `.on` later, use `.on`everywhere

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery

Comment: The above is true, but note that you'll need to be using a version of jQuery of 1.7 or newer to use `on`

Comment: @mplungjan it depends on the jquery version.

Comment: He is ALREADY using .on

Comment: Have you tried running your code? If you have, are you getting any errors? What troubleshooting have you tried? Try adding `console.log()` events to track the progress of the script to identify where it fails.
More exact information on your problem = more exact answers from the people trying to help you.

Comment: Provide HTML snippet as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a jquery datepicker to select your date it is easy:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
{    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        alert('this what you looking for?');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As live is depricated you should use on.

Then I hope you are using datepicker plugin. So when your clickevent is not on the input field. You should use oninput or onchange event handler.

```
   $("input.Degree_date").on('input', function() { 
        $("input.add").attr("hidden", true);
        $("input.delete").attr("hidden", true);
        alert();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Input date,

```
 <input type="date" id="date">
```

Function to be triggered,

```
var call = function() {
    console.log('Trigger');
}
```

Jquery function on input date selection,

```
 $('#date').on('input', function() {
        call();
 });
```