# How to Change Specific Text in an Inputbox Directly on User Input?

Tags: javascript, text, input

I have an input field in my code: `<input type=text name=code id=code>`.

What I want to do is to convert a specific text to another one as the user types in the field.

Let me explain more. When the user enters <kbd>31546</kbd> in the input, I want that text to directly convert to <kbd>HELLO</kbd>.

I know this can be done using JavaScript/jQuery, but I can't have any ideas on how to achieve this. How can I?

<sup><sub>P.S. If it's easier to work with a textarea, I'm ready to change my input to a textarea.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>**EDIT:**</sub></sup> I got a code from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery) which detects any changes to an element,

```
 $('.myElements').each(function() {
   var elem = $(this);

   // Save current value of element
   elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

   // Look for changes in the value
   elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
      // If value has changed...
      if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
       // Updated stored value
       elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

       // Do action
       ....
     }
   });
 });
```

but I am not sure how to utilise this for what I want.

<sup><sub>*Please bear with me as I am yet a fledgling in this domain.*</sub></sup>

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relation between `31546` and `HELLO`?

Comment: I want to create a MyCode-to-English converter.

Comment: what is the relation between these? Are you using any conventions?

Comment: Not pre-written ones. I am making my own. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set up a keyup event for your input and then replace the value as the user types. For example:

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();

    var newVal = val.split('31546').join('HELLO');

    if (newVal !== val) {
        $(this).val(newVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup event as,

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#code', function() {
  $('#code').val(convertedValue($('#takeInput').val()));
})

function convertedValue(val) {
  return 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code you provided changes the input's data to `hello` on any keypress in the inputfield.

Comment: yeah right you can put there your converted values as you want as per input.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :--

```
   <input type="text" id="code">

    $('#code').bind('change click keyup onpaste', function(ele){
        var origVal = ele.target.value;
        if(origVal.indexOf("123") !== -1){
            ele.target.value = origVal.replace("123","Hello");
        }
    });
```