# How can I detect which input field received input using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div>
    <input id="input1" type="text" size="50" autofocus autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input2" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input3" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input4" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input5" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input6" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
```

Now, when a user types something in any input field and then press enter, I need to recognize which one received the input, then store that input's ID in a var and the typed content into another. 
So far I have this code which I use to recognize if enter has been pressed:

```
window.onload = function() {
    searchinput = document.getElementById("input1");
    if(!!searchinput) {
        searchinput.addEventListener("keypress", function(a) {
            var key = a.keyCode;
            if(key == 13) {
                var query = this.value;
                search(query);
            }
        });
    }
 };
```

But as you can see, it only works with a specific input field (input1 in the example), and it doesn't insert anywhere the element's ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery) (Note that this includes some vanilla JS solutions, too)

Comment: If a user has enter value in more than 1 text-boxes then what to do ?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the code I use when there is only one text box. 
As for what to do if a user enters a value in more than one field, I want the code to obtain only the content of the box on which enter has been pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` event to detect user key press and `e.wich` to check if the pressed key is code equal `13` (enter key), then get attribute you  want from current input using `this`, check example below.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if(e.which==13){ //click on enter key
        alert(e.target.id+'---'+e.target.value); // get the id and value of current input
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="input1" type="text" size="50" autofocus autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input2" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input3" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input4" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input5" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input6" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `jQuery`.

This is untested code, but something like this might work.

```
// 1. Give all input fields a class of all_inputs.
// 2. The following code should loop through each one and add the ID to the all_ids array.

var all_ids = [];
$('.all_inputs').each(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   all_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Be careful the OP doesn't contain Jquery tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("keypress", "input", function (event) {
    var intKeyCode = parseInt(event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (intKeyCode === 13)
    {
        alert("Input Id : " + $(this).attr("id") + "  Input Value : " + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input id="input1" type="text" size="50" autofocus autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input2" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input3" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input4" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input5" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input6" type="text" size="50" autocomplete="on">
</div>
```