# Show div after textbox is filled

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript code to show a invisible . The invisible  is only appearing after clicking on textbox `tb1`.

I am using an SQL query to fill the text in textbox `tb1`.

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('#tb1').on('change', function() {
   if($(this).val() != ""){
    $("#area2").show();    
   }
  });
 $('#tb1').focus('change', function() {
  $("#area2").show();
  });    
 }); // Closes window.load
</script>
```

Is there a way to show  `area2` when the text of textbox `tb1` is changed? Without clicking on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Comment: The `propertychange change click keyup input paste` solution didnt work for me. The <div> gets only visible after clicking or changing the textbox manually not when the textbox is changed from an SQL query

Comment: There are several solutions on the page. If necessary (*which is likely true for this case*) you can use the timer solution, the current accepted answer. If you are using ajax you might get around it by checking the `complete` function state via method.

Comment: So my textbox needs to look like this?

`<input type=text id=tb1 />
<script>
setInterval(function() { ObserveInputValue($('#tb1').val()); }, 100);
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a even listener on checkBox, So whenever there will be change in the value it will show area2. Above code can be written in this way to listen the event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('#tb1').on("change keyup",function(e){
  if(this.value!==undefined || this.value!==null || $.trim(this.value)!=="" ) {
    $("#area2").show();    
   }
  });
 $('#tb1').focus('change', function() {
  $("#area2").show();
  });    
 }); // Closes window.load
</script>
```

Comment: The OP isn't using a check box, and they are not using their mouse or key input to change the value. The value is changed from an SQL query, as in not by user click or key events.

Comment: I am not using a check box or something, just a textbox