# symfony set some prefix for form fill in beforehand

Tags: php, forms, symfony

want to ask for symfony2 form text type, I have two fields to fill in: one is username, the other is email. Code something like:

```
$builder->add('username', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', TextType::class);
```

To save effort, I want when the user fills in username, the email will automatically be username@qq.com by default. But the user still can modify email if he wants. How to achieve that in symfony form type? How to modify the FormType class and need to use javascript in html?
Thanks!

Comment: You want the email to be filled at the very moment the username is typed in? Then it is a JavaScript question and actually unrealted to Symfony, as the backend only cares for the values it receives

Comment: Oh, I see. any demo code for javascript? thanks!

Comment: You could do it [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/339rfesw/), or if you want to listen to all changes (and see the email input live while typing), read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Comment: hi kero thank you so much!! works perfectly!