# How to detect the change on input when it changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect the changes in input values when it is dynamically changed.
as the change on txt2 clear the value in txt1 . I need to detect that it has cleared or changed.

Onchange does not do that.

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" onchange="SetDefault();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
<br>



<input id="txt2" type="text" onchange="SetDefaultSecond();" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">

<script>
function SetDefault(){
      alert("Change1");
    }

function SetDefaultSecond(){
      $("#txt1").val('');
       alert("Change2");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I checked your code, typing in txt2 will erase txt1 but you need to use the jquery script(if you didnt invoke it) <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>,,

Comment: onchange is not fired when changed with JavaScript. You need to fire the event manually.

Comment: @odai I need to trigger that there is a change in value happened in txt1

Comment: @epascarello yes exactly , I am trying to find a way to detect the change dynamcally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Comment: There's no event for what you need (except `onpropertychange` in IEs, not useful in general though). Even [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) can't be used (can detect attribute changes of an input only). Hence the only way left is to use a timed function to check, if a value has been changed.

Comment: @teemu you are right on propertychange does not make the work unfortunately .
so you think I have to try to find another solution to this problem?

Comment: @myf you are right the question covers mine , however the answers does not work with me 
check that here
http://jsfiddle.net/yosraNagati/fXnFF/2035/

Comment: @YosraNagati The accepted answer, or the last snippet in Annabelle's answer in the post myf has linked is probably the way to go for you. I.e. execute a timed function to check, if any changes have happened.

Answer (score 7):

You can manually trigger the input event when you clear the first input like this:

```
<input id="txt1" type="text">
<br>
<input id="txt2" type="text">

<script>
$("#txt1").on("input", function() {
    alert("Change1");
});

$("#txt2").on("input", function() {
    $("#txt1").val('').trigger('input');
    alert("Change2");
});
</script>
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dr0oabj1/

Comment: It works but only for if it is empty val('') , I search for a way to detect the change in general 
as if the value is 4 and changed to be 6 ..etc

Comment: @YosraNagati It works by emptying the value and then triggering a change. You can change the val('') to whatever you would want. Check out the answer here for a snippet to detect any and all input changes without triggering the event manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery

Comment: Actually this field on my project is changed from different sources dynamically , and I want to detect when it get changed.

Comment: @YosraNagati Then the link in my last comment should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @YosraNagati now i get the point but it was not so clear from the question. in that case you need to use setInterval technique described in Kodie's link.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use **oninput** event to capture any change to an input. it triggers every time the value changes due to typing/pasting etc. difference between **onchange** & **oninput** is onchange only triggers after focus goes off the input where as oninput triggers every time values changes due to any reason.

```js
function SetDefault(){
      alert("Change1");
    }

function SetDefaultSecond(){
      $("#txt1").val('');
       alert("Change2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" type="text" oninput="SetDefault();" />
<br>



<input id="txt2" type="text" oninput="SetDefaultSecond();"/>
```

Comment: i see, you want the alert for txt1 when it's cleared by txt2 change. 1min plz

Comment: when it is changed generally , cleared or changed to another value

Comment: oninput does not detect with val() is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txt2").on("input",function(){

        $("#txt1").val('');
        console.log("Change2");

    })

    $("#txt1").on("input",function(){

        console.log("Change1");


    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    
    <body>
        
        Text 1 : <input id="txt1" type="text">
        <br><br>
        Text 2 : <input id="txt2" type="text">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#txt2").on("input",function(){

                $("#txt1").val('');
                console.log("Change2");

            })

            $("#txt1").on("input",function(){

                console.log("Change1");


            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kodies answer is right; just try this ultra simple example and then proceed to  [Detect all changes to a  (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949416/540955)

```html
<input id="txt1" type="text" oninput="console.log('input')" onchange="this.oninput()">
<br>
<button onclick="eval(this.textContent)">console.log('clearing'); txt1.value=''</button>
<br>
<button onclick="eval(this.textContent)">console.log('clearing <b>and triggering</b>'); txt1.value=''; <b>txt1.onchange()</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in txt2

```
 oninput="changeClass(txt2);"
```

and in script

```
function changeClass(text) {
    if(text.value==''){
        //code for clear txt1
    }
}
```