# Form Input Event Listener

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an input form that is being dynamically updated with JavaScript. Using d3, I want to create an event listener that will run a function every time this input is manipulated.

Currently, it will run if I manually change the input field, but not if it is  updated using the JavaScript. I have tried using `.on("change",...` and `.on("input",...`.

Here is an example of the functionality I am trying to get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<input value="0" id="input1">
<button  onclick="clickFunc();">Click Me</button>


<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.select("#input1").on("input", function() {
// not printing when updated by javascript
  console.log('value changed');
});

function clickFunc() {
    document.getElementById('input1').value = document.getElementById('input1').value + 1;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `MutationObserver` window class to observe an input's change triggered by JS.

Keep in mind that simply setting input's node `value` property, for instance, won't trigger `MutationObserver`. You have to invoke `setAttribute(value, "value")` to get the change picked up by `MutationObserver`.

Here's a working example I've made: https://codepen.io/Inlesco/pen/rmxdpz

Of course, this is a vanilla JS solution. If you don't care about vanilla and using `jQuery` is a desirability, you can attempt to use this `jQuery`-fied answer: [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Though, I can't guarantee it'll work. Have not tested.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute functions with the `oninput=""` attribute in an `input` element.

```
<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">
```

In **JS**, you can also use:

```
$("myobject").oninput = function(){myScript};
```

or you are better with this one:

```
$("myobject").addEventListener("input", myScript);
```