# deny page to refresh if the text box is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check text box if it is not empty, else refresh the page.

I tried to check if the id of the **textbox is == null** then the page will refresh every 5 seconds and if its **!= null or not empty** the page doesn't refresh.

based on the request of 20yco is the full code:

```
{% block body %}
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/simpleInformation.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/simpleInformationSearch.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
{#   refresh the page each 50 second   #}
<script type="text/javascript">

// if($('#opinion').val() == null ){
//     window.setInterval(function () {
//         location.href = " ";
//     }, 5000);
// } 

var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);

 $('#opinion').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });


</script>

<form class="form-style-9">
      <!-- {{ Queryresult }} -->

<table border="1" style=" border-style:solid; width: 100%; ">
<thead>
<tr style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;">
    <th style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #2D77A2;
  color: white;">
add opinion
    </th>
    <th style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #2D77A2;
  color: white;" >
            num
    </th>
    <th style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #2D77A2;
  color: white;">
        title
    </th>
    <th style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #2D77A2;
  color: white;">
        date
    </th>
    <th style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px; background-color: #2D77A2;
  color: white;">
        description
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for item in Queryresult %}

    <tr style=" text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
    <td style=" text-align: center;" >
        <a href="#" class="te2">
                 {{ item.te2chira_id }}
        </a>
    </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center;">
  {{ item.num }}
    </td>
    <td style=" text-align: center;">
        {{ item.title }}
    </td>
    <td style=" text-align: center;">
        {{ item.te2chira_date }}
    </td>
    <td style=" text-align: center;">
        {{ item.description }}
    </td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
</table>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="hidden" id="theid">

    <input type="date" name="field2" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="date" id="date" readonly/>

</li>

<li>
    <input type="number" name="field3" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="num" id="num" readonly/>
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="field4" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="title" id="title" readonly/>
</li>
<li>
<textarea name="field5" class="field-style" placeholder="description" id="text" readonly></textarea>
</li>
<li>
    <table id="opinions_table" class="searchte2chira">

</table>
</li>
    <br>

<li>
<textarea name="field5" class="field-style" placeholder="opinion" id="opinion"></textarea>
</li>

<li>
<input type="submit" class="field-style field-full align-none" value="Add opinion " id="updateform" />
</li>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      var theSections={}
    $('.te2').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
       $.ajax({
           'method':'POST',
           'url':'/getTe2chira',
           'data':{
               id:$(e.target).text()
           },
            headers: {
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                        }
       }).done(function (msg) {
           console.log(msg)

           $('#year').val(msg['te2']['year'])
           $('#date').val(msg['te2']['te2chira_date'])
           $('#num').val(msg['te2']['num'])
           $('#title').val(msg['te2']['title'])
           $('#text').val(msg['te2']['description'])
           $('#theid').val(msg['te2']['te2chira_id'])
            $.ajax({
                'method':'POST',
                'url':'/getOpinion',
                'data':{
                    'id':$('#theid').val()
                },
                 headers: {
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                        }
            }).done(function(resps){
                //console.log(resps)
                var respsO=resps['opinions']
                theSections=resps['sections']
                console.log(respsO)
                opinionsTable.clear().rows.add(respsO).draw()

            })
       }).fail(function (xhr,e,r) {
            //console.log(xhr)
        })

    })
    $('#updateform').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if($('#num').val().length == 0 ){
            alert('please select a valid record to edit')
        }else {


            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/updateinfo',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                },
                data: {
                    'te2chira_id': $('#theid').val(),
                    'opinion': $('#opinion').val()
                }

            }).done(function (msg) {
                console.log(msg)
                document.location = '/simpleInformation.html'
            }).fail(function (xhr, e, r) {
                console.log(xhr)
            })
        }
    })
      var opinionsTable=$('#opinions_table').DataTable({
          searching: false, paging: false, info: false,
          columns:[
              {'title':'sec','data':'section',
                  "render":function(val,type,row,meta){
                            console.log('the Value is ',val)
                            if (type == 'set'){
                                console.log('doing here ')
                                row.section = val
                                row.section_display=sections[row.section]
                                row.section_filter=sections[row.section]
                                return
                            }else if (type === 'display',val) {
                                console.log('display')
                                return theSections[val];
                            }
                            else if (type === 'filter') {
                                console.log('filter',val)
                                return row.section_filter;
                            }
                            // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
                            return row.section;
                        }},
              {'title':'opinion','data':'opinion'}
          ]
      })
  })

</script>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

this is the chunck of code that i need to fix it :

```
<textarea name="field5" class="field-style" placeholder="opinion" id="opinion"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    if($('#opinion').val() == null ){
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = " ";
        }, 5000);
    } 
    </script>
```

If the textbox with id option has an input from the user that means it is not empty so the page will not refresh. Otherwise, if it is empty the page must refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: You may need to use setInterval

Comment: @TusharWalzade i did not understand your comment

Comment: Try to compare it to empty string ( ('#opinion').val()  === '' ) instead of null.

Comment: @pydev please check as right answer if it was helpful for you, thanks

Comment: @MirzaMašić i tried with empty string but still not working

Comment: You can effectively use jQuery formWatcher here, refer this - https://jquery-form-watcher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @pydev check it out here, it is working -> https://jsfiddle.net/mirzamasic/mxcLh24e/3/

Comment: @MirzaMašić the same issue it refresh even if it not empty

Comment: The problem is that when the page is loaded, input field is empty -> it checks it and starts the countdown to refresh. It doesn't matter if you later on have input some value

Comment: yes  that is the problem so how can i  deny the page to refresh of to stop the countdown once the text box is not empty ?

Comment: @pydev please check updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, by default, page will reload every 5 seconds, but if you fill input - page will stop reloading, but then, if you fill input empty again - page will start reload again every 5 seconds, to avoid this, just remove `myTimer` inside `if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {}`

**Updated:**

```
 // define timer that reload page every 5 seconds;
 var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 // input events
 $('#opinion').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        // if you leave input empty again - page start reloading again
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        // if input not empty - clear interval and stop reload page
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/asknef6y/31/)**

**[Screencast](https://monosnap.com/file/RB7AKpt4R2m7zll5c4xk8XqrUJ5zRA)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186387/discussion-on-answer-by-20yco-deny-page-to-refresh-if-the-text-box-is-not-empty).

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a scenario using `formwatcher` for you, where -

> jQuery will inform you only when you fill a **form input** or on clearing a form input. The page will only be refreshed once after a form input is cleared. So, please ***refer to this solution only if you are okay with this scenario***; otherwise, you may refer to ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)*** similar question.

Here's the **[plnkr](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/QKTKRZTEfOkDSGQY65VI?p=preview)** & **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s26qbjhf/3/)** demo for the scenario mentioned above. Remember to see console for output logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
    event.preventDefault();

    // check if everything is filled.
    event.returnValue = 'Did you fill the whole form?';
});
```