# How safe/reliable/cross-browser compatible is $(this)[0].defaultValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would appreciate some feedback regarding the use of $(this)[0].defaultValue for determining whether a textbox value has change from the original value e.g.

```
//keyUp event

if($(this)[0].defaultValue != $(this).val())
{
   //Field has been modified mark as dirty
}
```

In Chrome it seems to generate the desired output in the sense that the defaultValue is always the original value the textbox was loaded into the DOM with. However I have only recently discovered this value after crawling through DOM objects in the Chrome Dev tools looking for something completely different and I am concerned that it may come with a whole heap of problems. Additionally Google didn't turn much up which concerns me even more...

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems pretty safe. i just used this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rXsrQ/ and tested it across chrome/firefox 3.6/safari 4/ ie8, they all behave the same.

It is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement and there is no notice about compatibility issues.

It is also described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533718(v=vs.85).aspx and seems to be compatible with ie 5 and up, so i don't seem why it shouldn't be safe to use.

Comment: thanks for the answer I am going to give my vote to you because your answer was more directly targeted to the original question. @jAndy - I would mark yours correct too if I could because your answer offers an excellent alternative.

Answer (score 4):

`.defaultValue` is non-standard and therefore not mentioned in any *W3C* draft / specifications. If you're in charge of the HTML markup being rendered, the *HTML5* `data-` attributes seem to be a very convenient way to get the desired behavior cross-browser.

So you could render it like

```
<input type="text" value="foo" data-default="foo" />
```

jQuery will grab those `data-` attributes and store the part behind `-` as key in its *data expand object* for that specific node. That means you can just access those values by calling

```
$('input').data('default') // === 'foo'
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/zAuPf/

Comment: I like both answers - forgive my ignorance but will this still work in a non-Html5 compatible browser - my guess is yes because to jQuery it's just another attribute? I am itching to get into HTML5 but I have to restrain myself and finish my current project before I start "playing". Additionally the section of my site that I need this solution for is tucked away from search engines so I am not concerned about w3c compliance in relation to potential SEO penalties which still seems to be a little up-in-the-air in relation to the transition to HTML5. So this could be a robust alternative

Comment: @DrRob: yes indeed, this will work with non-HTML5 browsers aswell.

Comment: thanks again - I actually went with you alternative and it's working nicely - I decided I want to use $(this)[0].defaultValue on checkboxes too and low-and-behold it didn't seem to work - I kept getting "true" as the default value regardless of it's original state.

Comment: I am not sure if it is _non-standard_, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025

Comment: Haven't played with this but `HTMLInputElement.defaultChecked` for checkboxes? from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement