# jQuery: how to test input text against input value attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

Following case: the page is rendered with the following …

```
<input class="textInput error" id="accountMailaddress" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="some@mailaddress.com">
```

So I see an input with "some@mailaddress.com" already filled out.
If the user changes the text inside of it the value attribute of the input doesn't change in my dom-inspector. So I assume it's possible to test the text that the user just typed against the original value (in the value attribute).

How can I do so?

Thank you in advance.

more info …

e.g. I'm logging `$('.textInput').val();` on every keypress, val(); always holds the current text the user enters. Do I just have to store the original value in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#accountMailaddress').val() == $('#accountMailaddress')[0].defaultValue
```

also, defaultValue is [cross browser compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/how-safe-reliable-cross-browser-compatible-is-this0-defaultvalue)

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this:

```
   var defaultText = $('.textInput').val();

   if($('.textInput').val() == defaultText){
      // Email address matched
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that using the jquery attr method would work, without having to store the default value first. Something like this:

```
if ($('.textInput').val() == $('.textInput').attr('value'){
   // Email address matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do seomthign like this

```
var previousValue ;
$('.textInput').focus(function () {
previousValue = $(this).val();
})
.change(function () {
if(previousValue==$(this).val())
  //then do something
});
```

but the above is when the user changes it only once to make it comprehnsive

```
$('.textInput').focus(function () {
if($(this).data("key")!==undefined)
    $(this).data("key")= $(this).val();
})
.change(function () {
if($(this).data("key")==$(this).val())
  //then do something
});
```

I really like the defaultValue property too..