# Does an input have an "original value" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, default-value, html-input

With the latest changes to jQuery there are the different methods, `.prop()` `.attr()`.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to get the original value of the input when the page was loaded?

I know I could do:

```
$('#input').data('originalValue', $('#input').val());
```

and then I can refer to it through

```
$('#input').data('originalValue');
```

But I thought that since I can say, [find out the original checked state of a checkbox](http://jsbin.com/iqugup/2/) I thought maybe there is something similar for the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the input element's [`defaultValue` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement)

For example:

```
$('#input')[0].defaultValue
```

Note how by treating the jQuery object as an array we are able to directly access the DOM node and its native property.

See [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbQ4K/)

Comment: you can use placeholder attribute too

Comment: @salexch True. Why not post it as an answer too? Note however that `placeholder` is an HTML5 property that is limited to a specific set of input types.

Comment: it wont be a full answer. but maybe you could add it to yours

Comment: I am curious as to the cross browser compatibility of `defaultValue`?

Comment: Found the answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/how-safe-reliable-cross-browser-compatible-is-this0-defaultvalue

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the element and grab the [`.defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157) property:

```
$('#input').get(0).defaultValue
```

Or use [`jQuery.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) since jQuery 1.6:

```
$('#input').prop("defaultValue");
```

Likewise for `defaultChecked` (radio and checkbox) and `defaultSelected` (option).

Comment: I am curious as to the cross browser compatibility of `defaultValue`?

Comment: Found the answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/how-safe-reliable-cross-browser-compatible-is-this0-defaultvalue

Comment: See [**Interface HTMLInputElement**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025). Note that this does not mean that you are supposed to write `<input type="text" defaultValue="1">`;  it means that for `<input type="text" value="1">` the JavaScript object representing that object will contain the property `.defaultValue` with value = `1` even when user changes it to something else.