# Input jQuery get old value before onchange and get value after on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input text` in jQuery I want to know if it possible to get the value of that `input text`(`type=number` and `type=text`) before the `onchange` happens and also get the value of the same input input text after the onchange happens. This is using jQuery.

**What I tried:**

I tried saving the value on variable then call that value inside onchange but I am getting a blank value.

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted. The simplest way is to save the original value using `data()` when the element gets focus.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The simplest way is to save the original value using `data()` when the element gets focus. Here is a really basic example:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e4ovx435/

```
$('input').on('focusin', function(){
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

$('input').on('change', function(){
    var prev = $(this).data('val');
    var current = $(this).val();
    console.log("Prev value " + prev);
    console.log("New value " + current);
});
```

### Better to use Delegated Event Handlers

Note: it is generally more efficient to use a delegated event handler when there can be multiple matching elements. This way only a single handler is added (smaller overhead and faster initialisation) and any speed difference *at event time* is negligible.

Here is the same example using delegated events connected to `document`:

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'input', function(){
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
}).on('change','input', function(){
    var prev = $(this).data('val');
    var current = $(this).val();
    console.log("Prev value " + prev);
    console.log("New value " + current);
});
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e4ovx435/65/

Delegated events work by listening for an event (`focusin`, `change` etc) on an ancestor element (`document`* in this case), then applying the jQuery filter (`input`) *to only the elements in the bubble chain* then applying the function *to only those matching elements that caused the event*.

*Note: A a general rule, use `document` as the default for delegated events and not `body`. `body` has a bug, to do with styling, that can cause it to not get bubbled mouse events. Also `document` always exists so you can attach to it outside of a *DOM ready handler* :)

Comment: what happens if they change the value more then once without changing focus.

Comment: @bumperbox: If changes while the input has focus are important to you, you should be listening for key changes and not focus/blur events

Comment: Thanks, but I would suggest the name of the data is something like "prev_val", not "val", to reduce confusion.

Comment: @kristianp: If you feel `val` is an inappropriate name for the value, please do use anything else you like. I tend to prefix them with the plugin's initials to make it unique.

Comment: What if val is a file?

Comment: @mashi: It retains the local simulated file path as the value (the real file path is not available to most browsers). e.g. `C:\fakepath\test.docx`. Just change an input in the JSFiddle to `type="File"` and try it yourself.

Comment: focusout will resolve if they change the value more then once without changing focus

Comment: If you want to be able to change the select more then once without the user changing the focus, you could just add "$(this).blur();" at the end of the change event. That will force the user to change the focus after each change

Comment: does this work with select ?

Answer (score 10):

Definitely you will need to store old value manually, depending on what moment you are interested (before focusing, from last change). 
Initial value can be taken from defaultValue property:

```
function onChange() {
    var oldValue = this.defaultValue;
    var newValue = this.value;
}
```

Value before focusing can be taken as shown in Gone Coding's answer. But you have to keep in mind that value can be changed without focusing.

Comment: i find i consistently get 'undefined' for this.defaultValue. Mileage may vary.

Comment: @Brendan: probably you've missed value attribute

Comment: I am getting undefined as well. How do I pass the defaultValue?

Comment: The default value is the default value set to the field. Not necessarily the old value, if it was changed by the user and also "if there is no default value set, it may be undefined" - last statement hasn't been tested, just a guess.

Comment: defaultValue is not defined on the jQuery object, but on the DOM.  if you have a jQuery object, you can do `$jQueryObject[0]. defaultValue ` more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/how-safe-reliable-cross-browser-compatible-is-this0-defaultvalue

Comment: This will only work for the initial value. It wont detect the "old value" once it has been changed once

Comment: @Josh, thanks for the input. I need a solution for combo boxes, and this does not work for them. I'll try to update if I find a solution that does not rely on the value being stashed prior to the event.

Comment: [UPDATE] Nope... it seems there are no simple solutions for select elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076770/getting-value-of-select-dropdown-before-change

Answer (score 4):

Just put the initial value into a data attribute when you create the textbox, eg

**HTML**

```
<input id="my-textbox" type="text" data-initial-value="6" value="6" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#my-textbox").change(function () {
 var oldValue = $(this).attr("data-initial-value");
 var newValue = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: If you are using `data` attributes, then `$(this).data('initial-value')` has the same effect and is shorter. `data` attributes are merged with `data` stored on the element by code.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that works even with "Select2" plugin:

```
function functionName() {
  $('html').on('change', 'select.some-class', function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    var oldValue = $(this).attr('data-val');
    if ( $.isNumeric(oldValue) ) { // or another condition
      // do something
    }
    $(this).attr('data-val', newValue);
  });
  $('select.some-class').trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: If you are using `data` attributes, then `$(this).data('val')` has the same effect and is shorter. `data` attributes are merged with `data` stored on the element by code.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question today, but I'm not sure why was this made so complicated rather than implementing it simply like:

```
var input = $('#target');
var inputVal = input.val();
input.on('change', function() {
  console.log('Current Value: ', $(this).val());
  console.log('Old Value: ', inputVal);
  inputVal = $(this).val();
});
```

If you want to target multiple inputs then, use each function:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  $(this).on('change', function() {
    console.log('Current Value: ',$(this).val());
    console.log('Old Value: ', inputVal);
    inputVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Errr... Because this will assign the values from multiple controls to the same variable!

Answer (score 0):

my solution is here

```
function getVal() {
    var $numInput =  $('input');
    var $inputArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i < $numInput.length ; i++ ) 
       $inputArr[$numInput[i].name] = $numInput[i].value;
    return $inputArr;
}
var $inNum =  getVal();
$('input').on('change', function() {
    // inNum is last Val
    $inNum =  getVal(); 
    // in here we update value of input
    let $val = this.value;      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The upvoted solution works for some situations but is not the ideal solution. The solution Bhojendra Rauniyar provided will only work in certain scenarios. The var inputVal will always remain the same, so changing the input multiple times would break the function.

The function may also break when using focus, because of the ▲▼ (up/down) spinner on html number input. That is why J.T. Taylor has the best solution. By adding a data attribute you can avoid these problems:

`<input id="my-textbox" type="text" data-initial-value="6" value="6" />`

Comment: Actually the question was about retaining the value _prior to each edit_, not just the initial value, so this does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a current value and above options don't work, you can use it this way.

```
$('#input').on('change', () => {
  const current = document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My business aim was removing classes form previous input and add it to a new one.
In this case there was simple solution: remove classes from all inputs before add

```
<div>
   <input type="radio" checked><b class="darkred">Value1</b>
   <input type="radio"><b>Value2</b>
   <input type="radio"><b>Value3</b>
</div>
```

and

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
   var current = $(this);
   current.closest('div').find('input').each(function () {
       (this).next().removeClass('darkred')
   });
   current.next().addClass('darkred');
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkislin13/tybp8skL

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for select droplist, and jquery code would like this:

```
var preValue ="";
//get value when click select list
$("#selectList").click(
    function(){
        preValue =$("#selectList").val();
    }
);

$("#selectList").change(
    function(){
        var curentValue = $("#selectList").val();
        var preValue = preValue;
        console.log("current:"+curentValue );
        console.log("old:"+preValue );
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, but this only works for a single droplist. Best use data on the element instead of a variable.