# Is there a definitive list of characters which "number" input fields permit in html?

Tags: html

I'm working with an `input` field of type `number`, and I need to stay with this field type (using a `text` field is not an option).

The number field blocks most non-numeric characters, the exception being characters like `.`, `-`, and `+`. The field I am working with is only for non-negative integers, so I'm trying to block these by attaching an `onkeypress` handler, for example:

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('keypress', function (ev) {
    if (/* keyCode in list of undesired chars */) {
        return false; // preventing character from being added
    }
}
```

Is there a definitive list of what characters are permitted, or would I have more luck just enumerating the keycodes which the field *does* support?

I am aware of solutions like `jquery.numeric` but would prefer not to add another dependency.

Comment: If you only want 0 and up, use the `min` attribute: `<input type="number" min="0" />`

Comment: I think that works for stepping and validation, but it doesn't do any input blocking on the undesired characters.

Comment: since the keycodes you want are just [0-9]  checking against them is probably easier

Comment: If I had to guess which other characters may be accepted as part of numbers under specific circumstances, I'd say: `e/E` for scientific notation (as in 2.6e-17, which btw is a positive number), `0x/0X/0b/0B` for binary, `o/O` for octal, `h/H` for hexadecimal, and comma seperators (as in 1,000,000).

Comment: @m69 just tried, of those only e was accepted

Comment: @BIU with that, I'm concerned about keycodes for control keys like backspace, arrow keys, etc. As far as I'm aware it's not uniform across all browsers.

Comment: @m69 good catch, I didn't consider those. But even then, is behaviour uniform across locales/languages?

Comment: can you use the HTML5 pattern attribute? or is that only validation?

Comment: @BIU unfortunately, it's for validation as well

Comment: you could validate the field content itself on change - check that the new value is [0-9] and if not, reset to old value - apparently you can store the old value with .data() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118178/input-jquery-get-old-value-before-onchange-and-get-value-after-on-change

Comment: though i guess with continuous typing that's also not great :/

Comment: This: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html says the value of type=number is a float, which is then defined as an (optional) minus, some digits, an (optional) decimal point, some (optional) digits, an (optional) e or E, an (optional) minus or plus and some more (optional) digits.

Comment: @m69 that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Though I'm a little surprised that '.' is the standard decimal separator when ',' is used in many countries.

Comment: I guess accepting both dots and commas as decimal signs would lead to confusion with the grouping sign.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

In my browser, Vivaldi, I can do `-`, `+`, `.`, `E`, and `e`. To my knowledge, there are browser-specific differences, so it's hard to find a definitive list.

My browser version information:

```
Vivaldi 6.5.3206.39 (Stable channel) (64-bit) 
Revision    2e2a3967703f21a5a00e54e909f44f9c914f7be9
OS  Windows 11 Version 22H2 (Build 22621.2861)
JavaScript  V8 12.0.267.10
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Active Variations   5e3a236d-4113a79e
```

As for the use case specified in the OP's question `onkeypress` is deprecated, use `onChange`, `onInput`, or onBlur and access `event.target.value` via the first parameter.

If you want to know what they are so that you can prevent them, then I recommend limiting the input via JS: `/^\d+$/.test(value)`. One could use similar logic with a regular text input if they wanted to allow input of other ways of representing numbers, such as scientific notation using exponents, or BEDMAS/BODMAS operations.

Untested example:

```js
var valuePrev = 0;

function onBlur(event)
{
    value = event.target.value;

    if(!/^\d+$/.test(value) || value < 0)
    {
       event.target.value = valuePrev;
    }
    else
    {
        valuePrev = value;
    }
}
```

Use `onChange` or `onInput` for this to take effect while typing, but consider the async nature of the function, as it may have undesired behaviour when typing fast.