# jQuery - Compare new value with old value on form submit, across all fields (inputs, selects)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I was reading the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159046/jquery-change-event-on-an-input-element-any-way-to-retain-previous-value), but it solve the problem with just a single field, how would I watch all the fields (input, select, radio, etc...) on a form?

This is what I currently have (I'm using delegate, this form injects to the page dynamically):

```
$('#preferencesBody').delegate('input[type="radio"], select', 'change', function() {
    var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
    var value = $(this).val();

    // How to get the old value, and compare with the current value, if they are different, call saveUserPreferences?

    Preferences.saveUserPreferences(key, value);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rolled my own implementation, using an additional attribute when binding my data, and checking the value against the value of the additional attribute, i.e:

```
$('#preferencesBody').delegate('input[type="text"]:not(.password)', 'blur', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var currentValue = $(this).attr('data-currentvalue');

    if (value !== currentValue) {
        $(this).attr('data-currentvalue', value);
        Preferences.saveUserPreferences(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery has a system built in, exactly for this kind of stuff. Check [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159245/540352)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#formID :input')`

will select all input fields (including textarea's and buttons) on a form with `id=formID`

so your function would look like this..

```
$('#preferencesBody').delegate(':input', 'change', function() {
  var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
  var value = $(this).val();

  Preferences.saveUserPreferences(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Okay, but how about storing/comparing the new value with old value? :)

Comment: you should check for that inside the `saveUserPreferences()` function

Comment: I KNOW where to check, and of course I can do a zillian things to check for it (call my database to get the current value, store the current value, etc...) I was reading the other article (in my original post) and wonder how to make it work across multiple inputs, as I think the solution in that post (for a single element) is brilliant.