# With multiple select how can we know that user selected or un-selected some value?

Tags: jquery, select

Consider simple multiple select box

```
<select name="waste" id="waste" multiple>
<option value="5">garbage</option>
<option value="6">food</option>
<option value="8">Tin</option>
<option value="9">Can</option>
</select>
```

All it does is fire change event

```
$('#waste').change(function(){
//Inside here how will I know that this event was fired when user removed some values from selection 
// or did he added more values in selection
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159046/jquery-change-event-on-an-input-element-any-way-to-retain-previous-value ; this might help. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example : http://jsfiddle.net/7rf9J/

```
(function() {
    var s = $('#waste'),
      var  i = s.val().length;

    s.change(function(){
        var l = $(this).val().length;
        if (l === i) {
            console.log('you\'ve not changed selected value/s');   
        }
        else {
            if (l > i) {
                console.log('you inserted value/s');  
            }
            else {
                console.log('you removed value/s');             
            }
        }
        i = l;
    });
}());
```

I've enclosed your function in an immediate self execute function in which I declared a variable containing the number of selected items. Every time you add o remove an item I save the current length of the value (initially set to 0), so you know if you added, removed or changed selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#waste').change(function(){
    var selected=$(this).val();
    // selected now contains an array of the selected values
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUcRe/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example that would do exactly what you need.
The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hesher/3M36e/5/

The code:

```
var prevarray = [];

$("select").change(function(event) {
    var
    thisarray = $(event.currentTarget).children(":selected").map(function(index, item) {
        return $(item).text()
    });



    for (i = 0; i < thisarray.length; i++) {
        var anoption = thisarray[i];
        if ($.inArray(anoption, prevarray) === -1) {

            console.log("added " + anoption);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < prevarray.length; i++) {
        var anoption = prevarray[i];;
        if ($.inArray(anoption, thisarray) === -1) {
            console.log("removed " + anoption);
        }
    }

    prevarray = thisarray;

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="waste" id="waste" multiple>
    <option value="5">garbage</option>
    <option value="6">food</option>
    <option value="8">Tin</option>
    <option value="9">Can</option>
</select>
<p></p>
```

and js is:

```
function displayVals() {
     var wasteValues = $("#waste").val() || [];
     $("p").html("<b>Values:</b> " + multipleValues.join(", "));
   }
   $("#waste").change(displayVals);
   displayVals();
```

or check this out: http://api.jquery.com/val/  hope this help you :]