# When choose 3 items then select from 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, count

I have a script, when I choose lets say 4 items/persons, the other 3 select dropdowns have only 4 items max to select. When I select 3 items into one of these select dropdowns I need to be able to select only 1 left over item into the other two select dropdowns.

If you look at my fiddle you might understand better what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5MU/

Does anyone knows how I can do this?

```
jQuery.fn.filterOn = function(selectFrom, values) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var options = [];
            $(select).find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
            });
            $(select).data('options', options);
            console.log(selectFrom);
            $(selectFrom).change(function() {
                var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
                var haystack = values[$(this).val()];
                console.log(haystack);
                $.each(options, function(i) {
                    var option = options[i];
                    if($.inArray(option.value, haystack) !== -1) {
                        $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );
                    }
                });
            });            
        });
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#product1, #product2, #product3 ').filterOn('#personen', 
        {
            '0': ['0'],
            '1': ['0','1'],
            '2': ['0','1','2'],
            '3': ['0','1','2','3'], 
            '4': ['0','1','2','3' ,'4'],
            '5': ['0','1','2','3' ,'4' ,'5'], 
            '6': ['0','1','2','3' ,'4' ,'5' ,'6'],
            '7': ['0','1','2','3' ,'4' ,'5' ,'6', '7']        
        });
    }); 

<form action="" id="bestelformulier" onsubmit="return false;">
<select id="personen" onchange="berekenTotaal()">
  <option value="0">Aantal personen</option>
  <option value="1">1 Persoon</option>
  <option value="2">2 Personen</option>
  <option value="3">3 Personen</option>
  <option value="4">4 Personen</option>
  <option value="5">5 Personen</option>
  <option value="6">6 Personen</option>
  <option value="7">7 Personen</option> 
</select>


<select id="product1" onchange="berekenTotaal()">
  <option value="0">Geen</option>
  <option value="1">1 stuk</option>
  <option value="2">2 stuks</option>
  <option value="3">3 stuks</option>
  <option value="4">4 stuks</option>
  <option value="5">5 stuks</option>
  <option value="6">6 stuks</option>
  <option value="7">7 stuks</option>
</select>


<select id="product2" onchange="berekenTotaal()">
  <option value="0">Geen</option>
  <option value="1">1 stuk</option>
  <option value="2">2 stuks</option>
  <option value="3">3 stuks</option>
  <option value="4">4 stuks</option>
  <option value="5">5 stuks</option>
  <option value="6">6 stuks</option>
  <option value="7">7 stuks</option>
</select>

<select id="product3" onchange="berekenTotaal()">
  <option value="0">Geen</option>
  <option value="1">1 stuk</option>
  <option value="2">2 stuks</option>
  <option value="3">3 stuks</option>
  <option value="4">4 stuks</option>
  <option value="5">5 stuks</option>
  <option value="6">6 stuks</option>
  <option value="7">7 stuks</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5MU/1/

Lots of changes in the JS ... not really sure that's what you need.

```
var total = 0;
var hideAllAfterTotal = function(){
  var o = $(this), v = parseInt(this.value); 
  if(v > total) o.hide();
  else o.show();
};
$('#product1 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);
$('#product2 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);
$('#product3 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);

var berekenTotaal = function(){
  var s = $(this), i = this.id, v = parseInt(this.value);
  if(i == 'personen'){
    total = v;
  } else {
    total -= v;
  }
  $('#product1 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);
  $('#product2 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);
  $('#product3 > option').each(hideAllAfterTotal);
  $('#item').text(total);
};

$('#bestelformulier').on('submit', function(){return false;});

$('select').on('change', berekenTotaal);
```

Comment: Thank you allot Rafael! Thats exactly where I was searching for. :)))

Comment: Doesn't work in IE. thought on('change', needs to be ..on('click' , but doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: is it working with click? if so them no problem .... else try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159046/jquery-change-event-on-an-input-element-any-way-to-retain-previous-value

Comment: click doesn't work, I'll try that