# Detect the changes of the controls in a page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page with around 20 to 30 controls based on the query string values. I need to change a button as disabled based on the value changes in the controls. For examble in the list of Check boxes if something is checked or unchecked, some texts added or removed etc... for all the controls.

The controls are textbox, option buttons, check boxes, select controls and list boxes.

I don't want to add static methods to all controls. I do have an idea of doing the late binding to all the controls and to attach events. And that events will disable the button whenever the event gets fired.

Is there any other way to do this functionality in a simple way(Like Keypress or using event property window object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ekhaled pointed out you can use the same handler to handle all the click and change events.
Here's a somewhat convoluted example:

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="input1" type="text" value="" />
    <select>
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">EFG</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

and the javascript for it:

```
$('#container').on("change click", ":input", function (event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "SELECT") {
        if ($(event.target).val() == "2") {
            console.log("disable");
            $(":button").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(":button").prop("disabled", false);
            console.log("enable");
        }
    }

    if (event.target.id == "input1" && $(event.target).val() == "") {
        $(":button").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

[**See it working here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/2EsR8/)

However if you main concern is validation you should have a look at [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

With jQuery validation you can set specific rules for each of the inputs that will make up the validation of the whole form. It is very customizable, you can change where and how the errors are displayed, when is the validation triggered, etc.

Comment: @Rui- Please see my comments on previous answer.

Comment: As far as I know, if you need change tracking you'll have to keep track of the value yourself. You can use jQuery's data facilities, here's a link that can point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159046/jquery-change-event-on-an-input-element-any-way-to-retain-previous-value

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation and bind your event to the parent element, and then write all your logic inside that one event handler.

Can't really show you much, because you haven't included any examples or code. But something along the lines of:

```
$("body").on('change click', 'input, select', function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   if(_this.is('input[type=checkbox].className')){
     //follow one logic
   }
   if(_this.is('input[type=radio].className')){
     //follow another logic
   }
   //etc, etc
})
```

Comment: Here how can I track my changes, for example if its text box then how do i know that its has entered a new value or changed the existing value or removed the value. and for check box how can i know that whether that box is changed from checked to unchecked or unchecked to checked. Is there way to track before and after the event changes.

Comment: yes.. you are binding your handler to the `change` event (see code above). That event will fire every time anything changes in checkboxes or radio controls.  
It also fires in textboxes, but only after the textbox loses focus, so I guess you can bind to `keydown` as well as `change click`