# Get the old value of a widget from onChange event?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I get the previous value of a widget from before the onChange event happens? I know there's a `_lastValueReported` property on widgets, but it doesn't contain the value from before the onChange event. According to [this documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html#declarative-scripting-arguments), it seems that doing it declaratively inside my widget like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
<script type="dojo/aspect" data-dojo-advice="before" data-dojo-event="onChange" data-dojo-args="value">
    console.log('old value: ' + value);
</script>
```

I have a workaround in based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1159245/2486583) in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2atyksp/2/), but I figure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is watch(), it will give you both newValue and oldValue.

```
<script type="dojo/watch" data-dojo-prop="value" data-dojo-args="prop,oldValue,newValue">
    document.getElementById("statusContainer").innerHTML = "Old Value: " + oldValue + ", New Value: " + newValue;
</script>
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/moizhb/1ws1p0g9/). Hope it helps.

FYI, your other solution won't work if I am using only keyboard (tabs to gain focus) and change the value.

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution. Thanks!