# how to make a "Tr" visiable and invisable based on radio buttonlist click

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

i have an  **2 "tr"** under

1. tr one  have  an  file upload  control
2. tr  two  have  an textbox  control.

   so i have an  radio button list  woth three values 
   1:image
   2:video
   3:Audio
   by default i need  to  show  file  upload control  visiable that is  the  **1"tr".** but once user  clicks  on video/audio option  in radio button list  then i need to make **2 "tr"** visiable[ textbox] and **1"tr"** invisiable[fileupload control]
   so how  can i  achive this  functionality in javascript

   thank  you

Comment: You mean Visible or Invisible I think ?

Answer (score 5):

Give each row an id

```
<tr id="...">
```

Then set its visibility to hidden

```
document.getElementById("someID").style.display = 'none';
```

If you're using jQuery(and you should) you can make it really nifty with

```
$("#someID").slideToggle()
```

The nice part about that is that it keeps track of if the element is hidden or visible for you.

Answer (score 1):

So for this there is a simple answer and a complicated answer.  The main problem is how events are handled in IE.  In particular the "change" event only fires after you click the radio button and then click another element on the page.  In most of the other browsers it works fine.

For the **simple answer** my first response would be (assuming you are using jquery):

```
$("#idofyourradiobutton").change(function() {
  // Do stuff here like hide or show
  $('#trid').hide();
});
```

If you want full browser compatibility and you are worried about accessibility using the keyboard then follow this question's back and forth...

[SO Question #1720093](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

I leave the ASP to you...

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide both rows to start
    $('.foo').hide(); 
    // bind the right event based on browser
    $('.radios').bind(($.browser.msie ? "click" : "change"), function() {
          if($('#a').is(':checked') || $('#b').is(':checked')) {$('#file-upload').hide(); $('#text-box').show();}
      else if($('#c').is(':checked')){$('#text-box').hide(); $('#file-upload').show();}
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
  <form id="myform">
    <input class="radios" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="a" value="a"/>A<br/>
    <input class="radios" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="b" value="b"/>B<br/>
    <input class="radios" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="c" value="c"/>C<br/>
  <table>
    <tr class="foo" id="file-upload"><td><input type="textbox" value="file upload"/></td></tr>
    <tr class="foo" id="text-box"><td><input type="textbox" value="text box"/></td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**script in head tag:**

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function toggletr(val)
    {

    document.getElementById('trImg').style.display=(val==1)?'block':'none';
    document.getElementById('trUrl').style.display=(val==1)?'none':'block';

    }
    </script>
```

under body section :

```
<table>
                <tr id="trImg" style="display:block">
                    <td>
                        Image:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIage" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="trUrl" style="display:none">
                    <td>
                        Audio/Video Url:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbLst2" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True" onclick="javascript:toggletr(1);">image </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" onclick="javascript:toggletr(2);">Video </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" onclick="javascript:toggletr(3);">Audio </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want to be setting the display of table rows to "inline".

Comment: I have replaced 'inline' with 'block'.