# Jquery dependent dropdown doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a  3 dropdowns: countries, states, and cities.

States and cities are dependent of the previous form and loaded via AJAX.

In Firefox and Chrome everything is ok, but in IE (8 in my case) when I select a state, the cities dropdown isn't loaded. It is like IE don't detect the change. It is not a load problem, because I have tested with a simple alert box.

Any help will be really appreciated.

The states loaded page is similar to:

```
<select id="woeid_state">
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Florida</option>
</select>
```

The cities loaded page is similar to:

```
<select id="woeid_town">
<option value="100">Miami</option>
<option value="101">Orlando</option>
</select>
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    function loadStates( parent_woeid )
    {
        $('#states').load("<?php echo $states_page?>"+parent_woeid);
        return false;           
    }

    function loadCities( parent_woeid )
    {
        $('#towns').load("<?php echo $cities_page;?>/admin1/"+parent_woeid);
        return false;           
    }   

    $("#woeid_country").change(function()
    {
        //alert("I am an alert box");
        var country = $("select#woeid_country").val();
        loadStates ( country);
    });

    $("#states").change(function()
    {
        //alert("I am an alert box");

        var admin1 = $("select#woeid_state").val();
        loadCities ( admin1 );
    }); 

});
```

The form:

```
            <form class="ordinary_form" method="post" action="">
                <label>Country</label>

                <select name="woeid_country" id="woeid_country">
                                        <option value="23424975">United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="23424977">United States</option>
                                        <option value="23424979">Uruguay</option>
                                        <option value="23424980">Uzbekistan</option>
                                        <option value="23424907">Vanuatu</option>
                                        <option value="23424982">Venezuela</option>
                                        <option value="23424984">Vietnam</option>
                                    </select>

                <label>State/Province</label>
                <div id="states"></div>

                <label>City</label>
                <div id="towns"></div>
        </form>
```

UPDATE: usign JQuery 1.3

SOLUTION: brought by Daniel: replace the .change for .click

Comment: why do you have an empty div container? put the dropdown boxes within the div tags for state & city

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's counter-intuitive, but you need to use `.click()` instead of `.change()`.  Internet Explorer doesn't fire the `change` event until the dropdown loses focus, while the other browsers fire `change` each time the value changes.

See this related Stack Overflow question: [Getting jQuery to recognise .change() in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I replaced the .change for .click and it works. However it still works when I replace only the ("#states").click(function() leaving untouched the ("#woeid_country").change(function(). How come IE requires a click only in the states part and not in the countries part?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you load the state after the original javascript runs (and assigns the .change() event.
Use the form of

```
$("select#woeid_state").live('change', function() {
    var admin1 = $("select#woeid_state option:selected").val(); 
    loadCities ( admin1 ); 
});
```

to capture the event on the select.
EDIT: Put in the rest of the code

alternative as per note: add the event when you add the SELECT:

```
function AddSelectStateEvent()
{
$("select#woeid_state").change(function() { 
    var admin1 = $("select#woeid_state option:selected").val();  
    loadCities ( admin1 );  
}); 
};
```

and where you add the select:

```
AddSelectStateEvent();
```

NOTE:Fixed a syntax error in first option with .live (missing comma)

Comment: Mark:
Where do I need to put this code?
I have tried it 
-as a substitution for the $("#states").change
-leaving the $("#states").change and adding it below it
-inside the loadStates function

None of these aproaches has resolved the problem. 
Do you have more clues?

Comment: replace the #states part - the #states div only really changes when it is loaded, not when the select within it changes (assuming it IS injected into the #states div)

Comment: NOTE: as an alternative, you could put it in a function, and call that function when you load the states select - I will add an example for that...

Comment: NOTE: fixed syntax error on first option, missing comma after the 'change'

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried the first option. It works on FF, but I have the same problem in IE: it doesn't detect the change on the States dropdown

Comment: stupid me, forgot the :selected part duh, use the .val() for values and .text() for the text if you need that.