# jQuery; combine user click and :checked

Tags: jquery, checked, click

I have two blocks of code which basically check for 1) a click event on a radio button e.g.

```
$("input[id='frmSkill']").click(function(){ 
      //do something
});
```

And 2) a block of code to check if a radio button is :checked, if so, then perform some actions e.g.

```
if($("input[id='frmSkill']:checked").val()){
      //do something
});
```

What I'd like to do is combine the two in order to reduce the code as the actions performed under each are the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[id='frmSkill']").click(function(){ 
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          // do something, e.g.
          alert($(this).val());
      } else {
          // do something else
      }
});
```

I think you're looking for the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) traversal method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "change" event is more adapted to a checkbox:

```
    $("input[id='frmSkill']").bind('change',function(){ 
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         // do something
      }
    });
```

Comment: Checkbox `change` support is iffy with IE.

Comment: seems you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie  thanks

Answer (score 0):

A separate function that can be used in both cases:

```
function OnClickOrCheck(){
// code for both cases here
}

$("input[id='frmSkill']").click(OnClickOrCheck);

if($("input[id='frmSkill']:checked").val()){
OnClickOrCheck();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you all complicating everything?

```
$("input[id='frmSkill']").change(function(){
    // Your Code Here
});
```

Comment: Change won't work though. I'm using :checked to show the correct content after php validation, if validation fails, I need to know which content to show.

Comment: Are you using the callback function from ajax?
what you want need to be handled by ajax callback function, not by the change or checked function.