# How do I apply CSS effects on button activation via keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS style that changes the appearance of a (on-page) button while it is clicked. I would like to apply the same effect to the button when it is activated via the keyboard.

*(To recap: a button may be activated in a browser by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the button has focus, then pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>. Additionally, although it seems not to be officially specified, many browsers convert an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress to an activation of the (a) submit button provided that one of the input fields in the form has focus (excluding multiline text areas, for obvious reasons). [More details in this Stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined/925387#925387) )*

It is easy enough to apply the effect for mouse clicks with with the `:active` pseudo class. Some quick tests using Firefox 32, Chrome 41, and Internet Explorer 11 on Windows showed that FF did **not** apply the `:active` pseudo class when activating the button with <kbd>Space</kbd> (**which seems irregular**), while Chrome and IE do in fact apply it (which is what I would expect). None apply it when activating the button (inside `<form>`, `type="submit"`) via <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To obtain consistent application of the effect on a keypress, I was forced to go the JavaScript route (jQuery `$(xx).on()` event handler simplifies things).

Is there a non-JavaScript/CSS-only way to handle button effects on keypress activation? My guess is *no*, but would like hear other insights/experiences...

Here is some basic code: (The more complex button effect was replaced with a simple colored border, for simplicity sake. The colors are changed depending on the activation method, for more clarity - in the real system, they would all be the same style.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on("keydown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which == 13) { // enter on form (submit)
      $("#button").addClass("formenter");
    }
  });
  $("#form").on("keyup", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which == 13) { // enter on form (submit)
      $("#button").removeClass("formenter");
    }
  });
  $("#button").on("keydown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which == 32) { // spacebar while button has focus
      $("#button").addClass("spacebar");
    }
  });
  $("#button").on("keyup", function(ev) {
    if (ev.which == 32) { // spacebar while button has focus
      $("#button").removeClass("spacebar");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.mybutton {}
.mybutton:active {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.mybutton.spacebar {
  border: 5px solid cyan;
}
.mybutton.formenter {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="javascript:console.log('Clicked!');">
  <button id="button" type="submit" class="mybutton">Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Please check this

```
$("#button").bind('change keypress', function(e){
  // your code
});
```

Other wise you could get relevent similar example here:

[Change event not firing when radio button is selected with keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028936/change-event-not-firing-when-radio-button-is-selected-with-keyboard)