# $().change or $().bind(change,function()) doesn't work on IE8, JQuery,Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Code Example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

txtchangefunction();

});

function txtchangefunction(

$(".textCssClass").change(function () {

....});

or $(".textCssClass").bind('change', function())
```

both work for Chrome etc. but not IE8.

Can everyone help on that?? no console error comes out.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie ... specifically the second answer (which is the cleanest one IMO).

Comment: Your function is named `txtchangefunction` but you are calling `tExtchangefunction` - I'm presuming thats a typo!

Comment: @Steve Greatrex: Seeing that it works in chrome I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: did it work with element id?did you turn on the debug feature of ie to check where exception happen.

Comment: What type of element are you binding to? A drop down list? A textbox?

Comment: no exception, i think i tried before with a id.

Comment: @user508769:what about $.attr("onchange",function(){})

Answer (score 2):

I guess correct syntax is

```
function txtchangefunction(){
    $(".textCssClass").change(function () {
    //....
    });
}
```

or

```
$(".textCssClass").bind('change', function({}));
```

or

```
 $(".textCssClass").bind('change', funname);
```