# javascript jquery each problem in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.commission_plan').each(function(){
        total = total + Math.floor($(this).val());
    });
    $('#payment_total_amount_hidden').val(total);
    $('#payment_total_amount').text('Total: '+total);

    $('.commission_plan').change(function() {
        total = 0;
        $('.commission_plan').each(function(){
            total = total + Math.floor($(this).val());
            $('#payment_total_amount_hidden').val(total);
            $('#payment_total_amount').text('Total: '+total);
        });
    });
});
```

All work fine in FireFox, but in IE, when I change input value, nothing happends. But if I do it the second time all OK. Can you help me? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Surely you'd have to put last total setters out of `each` function (deosn't solve your problem, but makes your code correct(er).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known (and annoying!) difference between Internet Explorer and other browsers.  [This highly ranked StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie) should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

IE may not work the same way with `change` that Firefox does. You may try using something like `keyup` instead?

Also, you should move these lines outside of your `each`:

```
$('#payment_total_amount_hidden').val(total);
$('#payment_total_amount').text('Total: '+total);
```