# submit gets repeated after click when called on keyup of a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I post a form with `$.post` on the `keyup` of a `input type='text'`,
the problem is that after the post, I click anywhere in the browser (even on the firebug console) an the `$.post` is going to be repeated

**live link:** http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/lookupdemo

*(click on a button to open a popup, after search for a letter e.g. 'm' after click on something [watch the firebug console] )*

my **script** is something like this:

```
$('#theform input:text').keyup(function (e) {
        var w = e.which;
        if (w < 9 || w > 45 && w < 91 || w > 93 && w < 112 || w > 185)
            $('#theform').submit();
    });

$('#theform input:hidden').change(function () {
    $('#theform').submit();
});

$('#theform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
...
 $.post(...);
});
```

**UPDATE:** just noticed that without the `$('#theform input:hidden').change(...` all is ok

**UPDATE 2:** apparently the textbox also triggers change, strange cuz i registered the change for `input:hidden` not for `input:text`

**UPDATE 3: solved**, it looks like I should have used `input[type='hidden']` instead of `input:hidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some browsers, the change event (only?) fires when the input in question loses focus - that's why you're seeing another post when you click elsewhere on the page.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie) for more on that - it's about radio buttons, but the change/unfocus behaviour is similar.

And as for why the textbox got bound to the change event:  The `:hidden` selector does [a few more things](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) than just selecting inputs with the type hidden.  In this case, the text input wasn't visible on the page when your script ran, so it got selected too ('cause it was hidden!).

If you only want "true" hidden inputs to be selected, you'll want the somewhat uglier selector `$('#theForm input[type=hidden]')`.

Hope this helps!

**PS:** Changing the value of an input with JS [won't trigger the change event](http://api.jquery.com/val#dsq-comment-header-117202237).  Since an input of type hidden is presumably *only* changeable via JS, you should probably just call `$('#theForm').submit()` from wherever you change the hidden value.