# jQuery unbinding click event on a radio button that is already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, search, parameters

I am trying to create some parametric filters but i do not want to invoke the function that makes my search AJAX call when a radio button filter is already selected.

```
$('#contentType input:enabled').bind('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $type = this.type,
        $id = this.id;
    if ($type === 'radio') {
        if ($id === 'allContent'){
            sFrm.$boxes.attr({'checked': false});
            sFrm.$specificRadio.attr({'disabled': true});   
            searchAjax();
            removeFilter();
        }
    } else if ($type === 'checkbox') {
        if (sFrm.$boxes.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
            sFrm.$allRadio.trigger('click');        
        } else {
            var filterConfig = {
                index: $('.subFilter').index($this),
                txt: jQuery.trim($this.parent().text())
            }                   
            sFrm.$allRadio.attr({'checked': false});        
            sFrm.$specificRadio.attr({'disabled': false, 'checked': true}); 
            searchAjax();
            if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                addFilter(filterConfig);
            } else {
                removeFilter(filterConfig.index);
            }               
        }           
    }   
});
```

So the jQuery above looks at ALL enabled inputs in the collection and when a user clicks the *allContent* radio button the *searchAjax* function is invoked.

This is correct when said radio button is not already selected/checked.  At the moment the function is still invoked when the button is selected and i would like to stop this behaviour but cannot figure out how?

**EDIT**

Not sure i explained correctly.  Hopefully this jsFiddle will help:

http://jsfiddle.net/QsbRp/3/

Basically if *All content types* is checked already and is clicked when checked then *searchAjax* should not be invoked.  It currently invokes the function.

When it is not checked and clicked then it should behave as it is now (disable sibling radio button and uncheck all associated checkboxes).

Comment: Answer found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add at the top of your handler:

```
if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    return;
}
```

The event handler will return and not execute the rest of the function if the radio button is currently selected.

Comment: It works, but returns false on all radio buttons in the group. I am trying to use this with jQuery's `.on('click', function() {})` method. Am I missing something?