# Jquery Live Change Event not working with File Input

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Don't seem to be able to get this to work and not too sure why, for reference using JQuery 1.6.2.

I'm trying the below code:

```
    $("#imageUpload input").live('change', function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    var fileExt = fileName.split('.').pop();
    var indexPos = $(this).parent().index();
    var currId = $(this).attr('id');

    // check extensions and if invalid replaceWith the input to clear

});
```

IE 6 - 9 no luck whatsoever (nothing in the function gets called), Firefox it works flawlessly. I did a bit of reading and read the live + change issue with IE was fixed in version 1.4+ of JQuery. Also have exactly the same issue using Delegate?

Any help appreciated.

Is this an issue with IE and the file input type?

Comment: In IE the change event in jQuery = to blur in classic javascript

Comment: It seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when redeveloping [favikon](http://favikon.com/).  With the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1), IE7 and 8 would only fire the change event once.  I ended up having to do this to get it to work:

1. Bind a standard change event (i.e. not live) to file input
2. When the change event fires, submit the form
3. Immediately destroy and create a new file input
4. Bind change event to the new file input

[This jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5851) seems to be related, so I assume it's still a problem with IE that jQuery hasn't been able to work around.

Comment: Removing the .live('change', function() {  and just using .change(function() {  worked for me in IE