# jQuery MVC3 AJAX Callback to update DropDownList not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-6

I have the following jQuery to update a drop down list based on the selected value of another drop down list:

```
$("#FirstDropDownList").change(function () {
    $.get('/MyController/GetSecondDropDownListValues/' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
        var ddlValues = $.evalJSON(response);
        var ddlSecondDropDownList = $("#SecondDropDownList");

        // clear all previous options 
        $("#SecondDropDownList> option").remove();

        // populate the values of SecondDropDownList
        for (i = 0; i < ddlValues.length; i++) {
            ddlSecondDropDownList.append($("<option />").val(ddlValues[i].Id).text(ddlValues[i].Name));
            }
    });
});
```

It seems the callback only works when the submit button is pressed.

It seems the browser is throwing a 404 error. It works fine in Chrome, IE7+, Firefox etc. Unfortunately our client uses IE6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie][1]. Try using click instead of change.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie

Comment: Never ever use static definition of paths in mvc3! 

Use @Url.Action("GetSecondDropDownListValues") instead!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it seemed that IE6 wasn't resolving the path correctly. I altered it to remove the controller name from the path:

```
$.get('GetSecondDropDownListValues/' + etc
```

This seemed to fix it in both IE6 and newer versions of IE.

I have another issue where the callback shortens the width of the second drop down list (they're both set to 100%). Giving them a specific width fixes it, but it's not ideal. Oh, the pain.