# Binding "change" event revisited

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Years ago, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie) was asked, back in the days when jQuery didn't handle `change` events in IE. Supposedly, jQuery has fixed this bug so that IE can handle the change event. And indeed, I can normally get the `change` event to work.

However, in jQuery UI dialogs, using the latest version of jQuery (1.7.1) and jQuery UI (1.8.17), I can't get Internet Explorer 8 to recognize the `change` event. Instead, I find myself having to use something like the following for events bound in a dialog:

```
$("input").bind(($.browser.msie ? 'blur' : 'change'), myFunction);
```

Binding an element in a dialog to a `change` event works fine in all modern browsers like Gecko and Webkit perfectly.

Comment: Markup would help answer you better.

Comment: Change of any form element, but <input type="text"> in particular.

Comment: Does this simple example exhibit your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/p27CP/1/