# Is there an event for input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with `input type="file"` and another `input type="submit"`.

I hide the submit input until they click on the browse input.
But is there an event that is fired when they select a file?

If there is, then I can 'click' on the submit input for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the `change` event, just like with every other `<input>`

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie) and [this](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/145016-events-input-type-file) thread, becuase *Mozilla* and IE has problems with it...

the W3 spec:

> **onchange = script**
>
> The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This attribute applies to the following elements: **INPUT**, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Comment: Oh, ok.  That second link was from 2004. I don't think I can use the click event because I have to wait for them to select a file first.

Comment: @Pedro. Right... So it's probably working fine by now, I have not heard any problems with it lately(years...). Try it.

Comment: Maybe I could put a timer in there after the user clicks on the browse button, checking to see if the input has changed value.

Comment: @Pedro. Bad idea... Use it only if you have no other choice.