# change() event for select input in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm aware that jQuery's `change()` method doesn't fire for select and radio inputs in IE9. However, none of the workarounds I've found are working for me.

Here's the code that works in all decent browsers:

```
    $("select#orderby").change( function(e){
        console.log("order");
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
```

Here's a version of what I see people doing to get around this problem in IE9:

```
    $("select#orderby").bind( ($.browser.msie)? 'propertychange' : 'change', function(e){
        console.log("order");
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
```

This doesn't work when I try it. No errors in the console. Just nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** When I switch to the `.on()` method I can cause the page to reload (presumably as a result of the `.submit()` action) but the form select input isn't captured. The page simply reloads as if nothing was changed.

**IT WORKS!** But there was one other part that I overlooked which others might find useful. IE doesn't support the HTML5 `form="form_id"` attribute which lets you place a an form element outside of the `<form>` tags. So once I was able to bind the event, I also had to had to append the value into the form:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("select#orderby").bind( "propertychange", function(e){
        //console.log("order");
        var update = $(this).val();
        $("#candidate-filters").append('<input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="'+ update +'" /> ');
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
} else {
    $("select#orderby").change( function(e){
        console.log("order");
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
}
```

**I SPOKE TOO SOON:**
The code above only works in IE8 but not IE9. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use click()?

Comment: @Jason I can't use click because it's a select drop-down. So the event fires and submits the form before the user can make the new selection.

Comment: my bad, I saw "radio inputs" in your question and seemed to have ignored the select.

Comment: If you are using the jQuery version earlier than 1.5 then this is your issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8485

Answer (score 1):

This **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/xtKtS/)** seemed to work fine for me in jsfiddle for IE9:

**jQuery**

```
$("#test").on("change", function(){
    alert("test changed to: " + this.value)
})​;
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="test">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

There is the option of potentially using on `blur` as well, but it definitely depends on the specific situation.

**ALSO**, please be advised that `console.log` does not work in IE...and that could be part of your problem. As @MikeMcCaughan states in the comments, the console should work with IEs developer tools.

Please see the compatability table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input). It looks like the `form` attribute may not be supported in IE yet.

Comment: Note: `console.log` works fine in IE9, if you have the "F12 developer tools" open. It might still be part of your problem, but just to be clear.

Comment: I tried this with and without console.log. The page reloads but the new value doesn't get caught when the form gets submitted. It may be relevant that this select element is outside of the <form> element, but uses the form="" attribute to associate it, a la HTML5.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan for clarifying. I don't use IE any more than I have too, so I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @Emerson, that helps a bit. It seems your issue is a compatibility problem. Please see my update above. Also, whoever the phantom down vote was, please let me know and I'll make any necessary changes. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try changing

```
   $("select#orderby").change( function(e){
        console.log("order");
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
```

to

```
   $("select#orderby").click( function(e){
        console.log("order");
        $("#candidate-filters").submit();
    });
```

or using .on() or .live() , depending on your version of jquery  ,that has worked for me , it is also from [Here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie)

Comment: But the click event wont' work for a select input. The form will get selected as soon as the drop-down opens.